# What's the device code (platform string) for iPhone 5 / 5c / 5s / iPod touch 5?

Tags: iphone, ios, iphone-5

For example, is it "iPhone5,1" or "iPhone5,2" for iPhone 5?　And what's the difference？

If anyone has the iPhone 5, please help by running the following code and showing your result. Thank you.

Related Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3950748/482899

Comment: I have recorded user log since Sept. 12, and it seems that iPhone5,2 is more popular than iPhone5,1.

Comment: For iPhone 5S & 5C platform string, see this post 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18854244/what-is-platform-string-for-iphone-5s-5c/18900927#18900927

Comment: for iphone 6 and iphone 6 plus code is: iPhone7,2 and iPhone7,1

Comment: detect all apple known devices using this answer "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25780283/ios-how-to-detect-iphone-6-plus-iphone-6-iphone-5-by-macro/34542728#34542728"

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can find a list of all iOS device identifiers here (including iPhone 5 models and iPad mini):
http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=Models

The identifiers of the latest models are:

iPhone 5: iPhone5,1 and iPhone5,2

iPhone 5C: iPhone5,3 and iPhone5,4

iPhone 5S: iPhone6,1 and iPhone6,2

iPhone 6: iPhone7,2

iPhone 6 Plus: iPhone7,1

iPhone 6S: iPhone8,1

iPhone 6S Plus: iPhone8,2

iPhone SE: iPhone8,4

iPhone 7: iPhone9,1 and iPhone9,3

iPhone 7 Plus: iPhone9,2 and iPhone9,4

iPhone 8: iPhone10,1 and iPhone10,4

iPhone 8 Plus: iPhone10,2 and iPhone10,5

iPhone X: iPhone10,3 and iPhone10,6

**EDIT**: I also made an [updated version of the popular iOS Support Matrix](http://dorianroy.com/blog/2017/11/iphone-x-added-to-ios-support-matrix/) including all models up to iPhone X.

Comment: Link-only answers should always provide the critical information in the answer in case the link goes dead.

Comment: Fair enough. I've added the identifiers to the answer.

Answer (score 28):

```
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"])    return @"iPhone 2G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"])    return @"iPhone 3G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"])    return @"iPhone 3GS";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"])    return @"iPhone 4";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,2"])    return @"iPhone 4";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,3"])    return @"iPhone 4 (CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"])    return @"iPhone 4S";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,1"])    return @"iPhone 5";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,2"])    return @"iPhone 5 (GSM+CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,3"])    return @"iPhone 5c (GSM+CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,4"])    return @"iPhone 5c (UK+Europe+Asia+China)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone6,1"])    return @"iPhone 5s (GSM+CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone6,2"])    return @"iPhone 5s (UK+Europe+Asia+China)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,1"])    return @"iPhone 6 Plus";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,2"])    return @"iPhone 6";

if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"])      return @"iPod Touch (1 Gen)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"])      return @"iPod Touch (2 Gen)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod3,1"])      return @"iPod Touch (3 Gen)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod4,1"])      return @"iPod Touch (4 Gen)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod5,1"])      return @"iPod Touch (5 Gen)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod7,1"])      return @"iPod Touch (6 Gen)";

if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"])      return @"iPad";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad1,2"])      return @"iPad 3G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,1"])      return @"iPad 2 (WiFi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,2"])      return @"iPad 2";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,3"])      return @"iPad 2 (CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,4"])      return @"iPad 2";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,5"])      return @"iPad Mini (WiFi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,6"])      return @"iPad Mini";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,7"])      return @"iPad Mini (GSM+CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,1"])      return @"iPad 3 (WiFi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,2"])      return @"iPad 3 (GSM+CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,3"])      return @"iPad 3";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,4"])      return @"iPad 4 (WiFi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,5"])      return @"iPad 4";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,6"])      return @"iPad 4 (GSM+CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,1"])      return @"iPad Air (WiFi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,2"])      return @"iPad Air (GSM+CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,4"])      return @"iPad Mini 2 (WiFi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,5"])      return @"iPad Mini 2 (GSM+CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,6"])      return @"iPad Mini 2 (China)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,7"])      return @"iPad Mini 3 (WiFi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,8"])      return @"iPad Mini 3 (GSM+CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,9"])      return @"iPad Mini 3 (China)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad5,3"])      return @"iPad Air 2 (WiFi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad5,4"])      return @"iPad Air 2";

if ([platform isEqualToString:@"i386"])         return @"Simulator";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"x86_64"])       return @"Simulator";

return platform;
```

Comment: Is there a source for this on github or similar so I can suck this in and not have to find and update every time a release happens?

Comment: `Asis`? Do you mean `Asia`?

Comment: Note the harmless repeated iPad3.6.
I do this with
        static NSDictionary* deviceNames;
    
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        deviceNames = @{
            @"i386" : @"iPhone Simulator",
            @"x86_64" : @"iPhone Simulator",
...

and 
    NSString* readableName = (NSString*)deviceNames[machineName];

Comment: for iphone 6 and iphone 6 plus code is: iPhone7,2 and iPhone7,1

Answer (score 11):

This method covers all devices in market:

```
- (NSString *) platform{
int mib[2];
size_t len;
char *machine;

mib[0] = CTL_HW;
mib[1] = HW_MACHINE;
sysctl(mib, 2, NULL, &len, NULL, 0);
machine = malloc(len);
sysctl(mib, 2, machine, &len, NULL, 0);

NSString *platform = [NSString stringWithCString:machine encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
free(machine);
return platform; }

- (NSString *) platformString{
NSString *platform = [self platform];
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"])    return @"iPhone 1G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"])    return @"iPhone 3G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"])    return @"iPhone 3GS";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"])    return @"iPhone 4";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,3"])    return @"Verizon iPhone 4";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"])    return @"iPhone 4S";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,1"])    return @"iPhone 5 (GSM)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,2"])    return @"iPhone 5 (GSM+CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,3"])    return @"iPhone 5c (GSM+CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,4"])    return @"iPhone 5c (UK+Europe+Asia+China)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone6,1"])    return @"iPhone 5s (GSM+CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone6,2"])    return @"iPhone 5s (UK+Europe+Asia+China)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,1"])    return @"iPhone 6 Plus";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,2"])    return @"iPhone 6";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone8,1"])    return @"iPhone 6s";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone8,2"])    return @"iPhone 6s Plus";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone8,4"])    return @"iPhone SE";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone9,1"])    return @"iPhone 7";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone9,2"])    return @"iPhone 7 Plus";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone9,3"])    return @"iPhone 7";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone9,4"])    return @"iPhone 7 Plus";


if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 1G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 2G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod3,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 3G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod4,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 4G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod5,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 5G";

if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"])      return @"iPad";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad1,2"])      return @"iPad 3G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,1"])      return @"iPad 2 (WiFi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,2"])      return @"iPad 2";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,3"])      return @"iPad 2 (CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,4"])      return @"iPad 2";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,5"])      return @"iPad Mini (WiFi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,6"])      return @"iPad Mini";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,7"])      return @"iPad Mini (GSM+CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,1"])      return @"iPad 3 (WiFi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,2"])      return @"iPad 3 (GSM+CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,3"])      return @"iPad 3";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,4"])      return @"iPad 4 (WiFi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,5"])      return @"iPad 4";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,6"])      return @"iPad 4 (GSM+CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,1"])      return @"iPad Air (WiFi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,2"])      return @"iPad Air (Cellular)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,4"])      return @"iPad Mini 2 (WiFi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,5"])      return @"iPad Mini 2 (Cellular)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,6"])      return @"iPad Mini 2";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,7"])      return @"iPad Mini 3";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,8"])      return @"iPad Mini 3";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,9"])      return @"iPad Mini 3";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad5,3"])      return @"iPad Air 2";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad5,4"])      return @"iPad Air 2";


if ([platform isEqualToString:@"i386"])         return @"Simulator";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"x86_64"])       return @"Simulator";
return platform; }
```

Comment: for iphone 6 and iphone 6 plus code is: iPhone7,2 and iPhone7,1

Comment: Are you sure that this is what the code reflect? In previous models for example iPhone 5 the 6,1 & 6,2 where the iPhone 5 but with GSM and GSM+CDMA.

Answer (score 4):

Yup, "iPhone5,1" is the GSM iPhone 5, "iPhone5,2" is the CDMA iPhone 5, "iPhone5,3" is the GSM iPhone 5C, "iPhone5,4" is the CDMA iPhone 5C, "iPhone6,1" is the GSM iPhone 5S, and "iPhone6,2" is the CDMA iPhone 5S. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 3):

The Verizon iPhone 5 returns "iPhone5,2". The GSM phone returns "iPhone5,1".

Answer (score 3):

It looks like either iPhone5,1 or iPhone5,2 depending on the model of iPhone 5.

From @marcoarment, who is a well known iOS Developer:

> iPhone5,1: model A1428, AT&T/Canada
>
> iPhone5,2: model A1429, all others
>
> A1429 may have two modes, but I don’t see any iPhone5,3 records.

Source: https://twitter.com/marcoarment/status/249249183029161984

Answer (score 1):

I created a library for detecting the device at runtime.

It's called [SDVersion](http://github.com/sebyddd/sdversion).

Thought some may found it useful.

Answer (score 1):

[Update]

iPhone10,1 : iPhone 8

iPhone10,2 : iPhone 8 Plus

iPhone10,3 : iPhone X Global

iPhone10,4 : iPhone 8

iPhone10,5 : iPhone 8 Plus

iPhone10,6 : iPhone X GSM

iPhone11,2 : iPhone XS

iPhone11,4 : iPhone XS Max

iPhone11,6 : iPhone XS Max Global

iPhone11,8 : iPhone XR

iPhone12,1 : iPhone 11

iPhone12,3 : iPhone 11 Pro

iPhone12,5 : iPhone 11 Pro Max

iPhone12,8 : iPhone SE 2nd Gen

Answer (score 0):

check out your answer over here [How to detect iPhone 5 (widescreen devices)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446990/how-to-detect-iphone-5). till now i have not found any answer until some one developer buy iPhone 5 and post some useful information