# iOS How to detect iPhone X, iPhone 6 plus, iPhone 6, iPhone 5, iPhone 4 by macro?

Tags: iphone, macros, detect

How to detect device model by macro?
i had using something like this but the result on the simulator alway IS_IPHONE_5

```
#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#define IS_IPHONE (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
#define IS_IPHONE_5 (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_6 (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 667.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_6PLUS (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeScale] == 3.0f)
#define IS_IPHONE_6_PLUS (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 736.0)
#define IS_RETINA ([[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.0)
```

Comment: the problem only present on old projects, every thing is ok with new projects(which be created by Xcode 6).

Comment: fixed by: create launch screen and delete all default launching images

Comment: You should use #define IS_IPHONE_6PLUS (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 3.0f) on actual iPhone6 device.  Not nativeScale.

Comment: [[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeScale] == 3.0f (or even scale) to detect an iPhone 6 Plus is wrong. These will report the wrong thing if you are on a scaled iOS app running on a 6+. nativeScale will never be 3.0 -- on a 6 Plus it is 2.60869 (since the physical screen is not a true 3x)

To detect the running environment it is fine to use scale, but to detect the device itself, you will have to use other methods like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197509/ios-iphone-get-device-model-and-make

Comment: @Milanpatel add launch screen xib to your project

Comment: Here the answer to detect iPhone X screen device. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46278776/5991255

Comment: take a look please https://stackoverflow.com/a/52821290/3472073

Answer (score 194):

### Swift

```
import UIKit

public enum DisplayType {
    case unknown
    case iphone4
    case iphone5
    case iphone6
    case iphone6plus
    static let iphone7 = iphone6
    static let iphone7plus = iphone6plus
    case iphoneX
}

public final class Display {
    class var width:CGFloat { return UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width }
    class var height:CGFloat { return UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height }
    class var maxLength:CGFloat { return max(width, height) }
    class var minLength:CGFloat { return min(width, height) }
    class var zoomed:Bool { return UIScreen.main.nativeScale >= UIScreen.main.scale }
    class var retina:Bool { return UIScreen.main.scale >= 2.0 }
    class var phone:Bool { return UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone }
    class var pad:Bool { return UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad }
    class var carplay:Bool { return UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .carPlay }
    class var tv:Bool { return UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .tv }
    class var typeIsLike:DisplayType {
        if phone && maxLength < 568 {
            return .iphone4
        }
        else if phone && maxLength == 568 {
            return .iphone5
        }
        else if phone && maxLength == 667 {
            return .iphone6
        }
        else if phone && maxLength == 736 {
            return .iphone6plus
        }
        else if phone && maxLength == 812 {
            return .iphoneX
        }
        return .unknown
    }
}
```

See it in action
https://gist.github.com/hfossli/bc93d924649de881ee2882457f14e346

Note: If e.g. iPhone 6 is in zoomed mode the UI is a zoomed up version of iPhone 5. These functions is not determining device type, but display mode thus iPhone 5 is the desired result in this example.

### Objective-C

```
#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#define IS_IPHONE (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
#define IS_RETINA ([[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] >= 2.0)

#define SCREEN_WIDTH ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width)
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)
#define SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH (MAX(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
#define SCREEN_MIN_LENGTH (MIN(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
#define IS_ZOOMED (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 736.0)

#define IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH < 568.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_5 (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 568.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_6 (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 667.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_6P (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 736.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_X (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 812.0)
```

Usage: http://pastie.org/9687735

Note: If e.g. iPhone 6 is in zoomed mode the UI is a zoomed up version of iPhone 5. These functions is not determining device type, but display mode thus iPhone 5 is the desired result in this example.

Comment: IS_IPHONE_6 and IS_IPHONE_6P do not appear work in the simulator.  The reported max length is 568. Am I missing something?

Comment: Is it in zoomed mode? Do you have a launchscreen for iPhone 6?

Comment: This looks like an overall incorrect direction to me. This will definitely break in the not too far future.

Comment: @Jonny: Alternatives?

Comment: I guess in most cases designing for a model is not a good choice for maintainability and can be avoided by checking for required features rather than exact models.

Comment: @Jonny: In general you are right, but I know an application, which would take advantage of this if you would know the model or at least the resolution. It is the week view in the calendar application which adapts the width of a day depending on the device type. WIth this an exact amount of days can be shown at the same time. Without this solution you see only parts of the other days.

Comment: if you are planning to distribute your app to millions of users, this is not recommended. Do check these results if user enabled "Zoom" (instead of normal "standard") in display settings of the device. This code will break in this case. I personally recommend to use mcm's answer.

Comment: yes, you have to check zoom too, otherwise, the height for iPhone plus is 667, see my answer below

Comment: any ideas how to identify 6S because of ram difference with 6 for image processing?

Comment: Then you should probably check available ram size instead of checking model

Answer (score 62):

For Swift:

```
struct ScreenSize
{
    static let SCREEN_WIDTH = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
    static let SCREEN_HEIGHT = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
    static let SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH = max(ScreenSize.SCREEN_WIDTH, ScreenSize.SCREEN_HEIGHT)
    static let SCREEN_MIN_LENGTH = min(ScreenSize.SCREEN_WIDTH, ScreenSize.SCREEN_HEIGHT)
}

struct DeviceType
{
    static let IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS =  UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH < 568.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_5 = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 568.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_6 = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 667.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_6P = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 736.0
}
```

Comment: No need for UIUserInterfaceIdiom enum, just import UIKit

Comment: if you are planning to distribute your app to millions of users, this is not recommended. Do check these results if user enabled "Zoom" (instead of normal "standard") in display settings of the device. This code will break in this case. I personally recommend to use mcm's answer.

Comment: Very nice. The static let properties makes this very efficient!

Comment: What about iPhone X?

Answer (score 15):

```
#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#define IS_IPHONE (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) // iPhone and       iPod touch style UI

#define IS_IPHONE_5_IOS7 (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568.0f)
#define IS_IPHONE_6_IOS7 (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 667.0f)
#define IS_IPHONE_6P_IOS7 (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 736.0f)
#define IS_IPHONE_4_AND_OLDER_IOS7 (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height < 568.0f)

#define IS_IPHONE_5_IOS8 (IS_IPHONE && ([[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeBounds].size.height/[[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeScale]) == 568.0f)
#define IS_IPHONE_6_IOS8 (IS_IPHONE && ([[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeBounds].size.height/[[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeScale]) == 667.0f)
#define IS_IPHONE_6P_IOS8 (IS_IPHONE && ([[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeBounds].size.height/[[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeScale]) == 736.0f)
#define IS_IPHONE_4_AND_OLDER_IOS8 (IS_IPHONE && ([[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeBounds].size.height/[[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeScale]) < 568.0f)

#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( ( [ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] respondsToSelector: @selector( nativeBounds ) ] ) ? IS_IPHONE_5_IOS8 : IS_IPHONE_5_IOS7 )
#define IS_IPHONE_6 ( ( [ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] respondsToSelector: @selector( nativeBounds ) ] ) ? IS_IPHONE_6_IOS8 : IS_IPHONE_6_IOS7 )
#define IS_IPHONE_6P ( ( [ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] respondsToSelector: @selector( nativeBounds ) ] ) ? IS_IPHONE_6P_IOS8 : IS_IPHONE_6P_IOS7 )
#define IS_IPHONE_4_AND_OLDER ( ( [ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] respondsToSelector: @selector( nativeBounds ) ] ) ? IS_IPHONE_4_AND_OLDER_IOS8 : IS_IPHONE_4_AND_OLDER_IOS7 )
```

Comment: `IS_IPHONE_6_IOS7` and `IS_IPHONE_6P_IOS7` are not needed, iPhone 6 (+) can only be on iOS 8 and above.

Comment: you mean to say iphone 6 and iphone 6 plus are only be able to install iOS 8 and later ? Am i getting your point ?

Comment: Yes - iPhone 6 (+) comes with iOS 8 and it is not possible to downgrade

Comment: This doesnt work since .size.height == 568.0f returns 320 when iphone 5 is in landscape

Comment: I test it on landscape too and its giving correct answer, tell me in detail please.

Comment: how would you do these checks in Swift?

Comment: According to documentation, screen bounds depend on orientation starting with iOS 8 (quote): _This rectangle is specified in the current coordinate space, which takes into account any interface rotations in effect for the device. Therefore, the value of this property may change when the device rotates between portrait and landscape orientations._

Comment: if you are planning to distribute your app to millions of users, this is not recommended. Do check these results if user enabled "Zoom" (instead of normal "standard") in display settings of the device. This code will break in this case. I personally recommend to use mcm's answer.

Comment: I need to identify 6S because of ram difference with 6 for image processing, any ideas?

Answer (score 15):

```
public extension UIDevice {

    var iPhone: Bool {
        return UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone
    }

    enum ScreenType: String {
        case iPhone4
        case iPhone5
        case iPhone6
        case iPhone6Plus
        case Unknown
    }
    var screenType: ScreenType {
        guard iPhone else { return .Unknown}
        switch UIScreen.mainScreen().nativeBounds.height {
        case 960:
            return .iPhone4
        case 1136:
            return .iPhone5
        case 1334:
            return .iPhone6
        case 1920: //fallthrough
            return .iPhone6Plus
        case 2208:
            return .iPhone6Plus
        default:
            return .Unknown
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: native height for iPhone 6 Plus is 2208 NOT 1920 - I corrected your answer.

Comment: +1. `nativeBounds` is better to use than `bounds`. An iPhone 6 with Display Zoom on will report 568 for bounds.height, but 1334 for nativeBounds.height, even though Display Zoom does not have any effect inside apps. (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203073)

Comment: @salocinx I get 1920.0 returned to me from Xcode for the iPhone 6/7 plus.

Comment: then we should use both cases here :- 

        case 1920:
        fallthrough
        case 2208:
            return .iPhone6Plus

Comment: iPhone plus is 1920 on physical device and 2208 on simulator because of downscaling from 3X density on device.

Comment: Thanks @AlessandroMartin

Answer (score 10):

I use a class that pulls actual system info. Just have to make sure all device types are up to date.

```
#import "Macros.h"

@implementation Macros

+ (BOOL)IS_IPHONE_6_PLUS {
    return [[self deviceType] isEqualToString:@"iPhone 6 Plus"] ||  [[self deviceType] isEqualToString:@"iPhone 6S Plus"];
}

+ (BOOL)IS_IPHONE_6 {
    return [[self deviceType] isEqualToString:@"iPhone 6"] || [[self deviceType] isEqualToString:@"iPhone 6S"];
}

+ (BOOL)IS_SIMULATOR {
    return [[self deviceType] isEqualToString:@"32-bit Simulator"]
           || [[self deviceType] isEqualToString:@"64-bit Simulator"];
}

+ (BOOL)IS_IPHONE_5 {
    NSString *device = [self deviceType];
    BOOL result = [device isEqualToString:@"iPhone 5(GSM)"] || [device isEqualToString:@"iPhone 5(GSM+CDMA)"]
                  || [device isEqualToString:@"iPhone 5C(GSM)"] || [device isEqualToString:@"iPhone 5C(GSM+CDMA)"]
                  || [device isEqualToString:@"iPhone 5S(GSM)"] || [device isEqualToString:@"iPhone 5S(GSM+CDMA)"];
    return result;
}

/*
 @"i386"      on 32-bit Simulator
 @"x86_64"    on 64-bit Simulator
 @"iPod1,1"   on iPod Touch
 @"iPod2,1"   on iPod Touch Second Generation
 @"iPod3,1"   on iPod Touch Third Generation
 @"iPod4,1"   on iPod Touch Fourth Generation
 @"iPod5,1"   on iPod Touch Fifth Generation
 @"iPhone1,1" on iPhone
 @"iPhone1,2" on iPhone 3G
 @"iPhone2,1" on iPhone 3GS
 @"iPad1,1"   on iPad
 @"iPad2,1"   on iPad 2
 @"iPad3,1"   on 3rd Generation iPad
 @"iPad3,2":  on iPad 3(GSM+CDMA)
 @"iPad3,3":  on iPad 3(GSM)
 @"iPad3,4":  on iPad 4(WiFi)
 @"iPad3,5":  on iPad 4(GSM)
 @"iPad3,6":  on iPad 4(GSM+CDMA)
 @"iPhone3,1" on iPhone 4
 @"iPhone4,1" on iPhone 4S
 @"iPad3,4"   on 4th Generation iPad
 @"iPad2,5"   on iPad Mini
 @"iPhone5,1" on iPhone 5(GSM)
 @"iPhone5,2" on iPhone 5(GSM+CDMA)
 @"iPhone5,3  on iPhone 5c(GSM)
 @"iPhone5,4" on iPhone 5c(GSM+CDMA)
 @"iPhone6,1" on iPhone 5s(GSM)
 @"iPhone6,2" on iPhone 5s(GSM+CDMA)
 @"iPhone7,1" on iPhone 6 Plus
 @"iPhone7,2" on iPhone 6
 @"iPhone8,1" on iPhone 6  
 @"iPhone8,2" on iPhone 6 Plus ...Yes Apple switched the order...
 */

+ (NSString *)deviceType {
    struct utsname systemInfo;
    uname(&systemInfo);
    NSString *result = [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        // https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Models
        NSDictionary *matches = @{
                          @"i386" : @"32-bit Simulator",
                          @"x86_64" : @"64-bit Simulator",

                          @"iPod1,1" : @"iPod Touch",
                          @"iPod2,1" : @"iPod Touch Second Generation",
                          @"iPod3,1" : @"iPod Touch Third Generation",
                          @"iPod4,1" : @"iPod Touch Fourth Generation",
                          @"iPod5,1" : @"iPod Touch Fifth Generation",

                          @"iPad1,1" : @"iPad",
                          @"iPad2,1" : @"iPad 2",
                          @"iPad2,2" : @"iPad 2",
                          @"iPad2,3" : @"iPad 2",
                          @"iPad2,4" : @"iPad 2",
                          @"iPad2,5" : @"iPad Mini",
                          @"iPad2,6" : @"iPad Mini",
                          @"iPad2,7" : @"iPad Mini",
                          @"iPad3,1" : @"iPad 3",
                          @"iPad3,2" : @"iPad 3(GSM+CDMA)",
                          @"iPad3,3" : @"iPad 3(GSM)",
                          @"iPad3,4" : @"iPad 4(WiFi)",
                          @"iPad3,5" : @"iPad 4(GSM)",
                          @"iPad3,6" : @"iPad 4(GSM+CDMA)",
                          @"iPad4,1" : @"iPad Air",
                          @"iPad4,2" : @"iPad Air",
                          @"iPad4,3" : @"iPad Air",
                          @"iPad4,4" : @"iPad Mini 2",
                          @"iPad4,5" : @"iPad Mini 2",
                          @"iPad4,6" : @"iPad Mini 2",
                          @"iPad4,7" : @"iPad Mini 3",
                          @"iPad4,8" : @"iPad Mini 3",
                          @"iPad4,9" : @"iPad Mini 3",
                          @"iPad5,1" : @"iPad Mini 4",
                          @"iPad5,2" : @"iPad Mini 4",
                          @"iPad5,3" : @"iPad Air 2",
                          @"iPad5,4" : @"iPad Air 2",
                          @"iPad6,3" : @"iPad Pro (9.7in)",
                          @"iPad6,4" : @"iPad Pro (9.7in)",
                          @"iPad6,7" : @"iPad Pro (12.9in)",
                          @"iPad6,8" : @"iPad Pro (12.9in)",

                          @"iPhone1,1" : @"iPhone",
                          @"iPhone1,2" : @"iPhone 3G",
                          @"iPhone2,1" : @"iPhone 3GS",
                          @"iPhone3,1" : @"iPhone 4",
                          @"iPhone3,3" : @"iPhone 4",
                          @"iPhone4,1" : @"iPhone 4S",
                          @"iPhone5,1" : @"iPhone 5(GSM)",
                          @"iPhone5,2" : @"iPhone 5(GSM+CDMA)",
                          @"iPhone5,3" : @"iPhone 5C(GSM)",
                          @"iPhone5,4" : @"iPhone 5C(GSM+CDMA)",
                          @"iPhone6,1" : @"iPhone 5S(GSM)",
                          @"iPhone6,2" : @"iPhone 5S(GSM+CDMA)",
                          @"iPhone7,1" : @"iPhone 6 Plus",
                          @"iPhone7,2" : @"iPhone 6",
                          @"iPhone8,1" : @"iPhone 6S",
                          @"iPhone8,2" : @"iPhone 6S Plus",
                          @"iPhone8,4" : @"iPhone SE",
                          @"iPhone9,1" : @"iPhone 7",
                          @"iPhone9,3" : @"iPhone 7",
                          @"iPhone9,2" : @"iPhone 7 Plus",
                          @"iPhone9,4" : @"iPhone 7 Plus",
                          };

    if (matches[result]) {
        return matches[result];
    } else {
        return result;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: #import <sys/utsname.h>

Answer (score 7):

I can confirm the bug goes away when you set a Launch Screen.

I kept my launch images, and added MainStoryboard to Launch Screen and the simulator recognized the devices correctly.

Comment: Agree this, for older projects without launchscreen its buggy. Launch Screen solved it.

Answer (score 7):

It's better not to bind your code with device types. This will lead to inflexible convoluted one. Apple wants you to think about sizes not devices. In case you need to have special sizes for devices larger than iPhone 5 such as image or font sizes, I would recommend to create a normalize class with a multiplier that grows your base size by a certain percent based on the relation between  the iPhone 5 screen width and the current device size.

```
let BaseWidth : CGFloat = 320

class Normalizer: NSObject {
    //scale value proportional to the screen width
    class func normalize(value:CGFloat,multiplier : CGFloat = 1,maxDelta:CGFloat = 1024) -> CGFloat{
        let screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
        let percent = (screenWidth - BaseWidth)/screenWidth
        let normalizedValue = value * (1 + percent) * multiplier
        return min(normalizedValue, value + maxDelta)//capped by a max value if needed
    } 
}
```

So in your code you will do something like that:

```
value = Normalizer.normalize(30)
```

Comment: Why not using a struct with a `static normalize` ?

Comment: It should work too but I think struct is mostly for handling data

Answer (score 6):

UIDeivce extension with **Swift 3+** syntax.

```
public extension UIDevice {

    var iPhone: Bool {
        return UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .phone
    }

    enum ScreenType: String {
        case iPhone4
        case iPhone5
        case iPhone6
        case iPhone6Plus
        case iPhoneX
        case Unknown
    }
    var screenType: ScreenType {
        guard iPhone else { return .Unknown}
        switch UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height {
        case 960:
            return .iPhone4
        case 1136:
            return .iPhone5
        case 1334:
            return .iPhone6
        case 2208, 1920:
            return .iPhone6Plus
        case 2436:
            return .iPhoneX
        default:
            return .Unknown
        }
    }

}
```

Sample usage:

```
switch UIDevice().screenType {
        case .iPhone4, .iPhone5:
            // Code for iPhone 4 & iPhone 5
            break
        case .iPhone6:
            // Code for iPhone 6 & iPhone 7
            break
        case .iPhone6Plus:
            // Code for iPhone 6 Plus & iPhone 7 Plus
            break
        case .iPhoneX:
            // Code for iPhone X
            break
        default:
            break
        }
```

Original answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36479017/3659227

Answer (score 5):

Update Xcode 13 / Swift 5.5:

```
    enum UIUserInterfaceIdiom : Int
{
    case Unspecified
    case Phone
    case Pad
}

struct ScreenSize
{
    static let SCREEN_WIDTH         = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
    static let SCREEN_HEIGHT        = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
    static let SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH    = max(ScreenSize.SCREEN_WIDTH, ScreenSize.SCREEN_HEIGHT)
    static let SCREEN_MIN_LENGTH    = min(ScreenSize.SCREEN_WIDTH, ScreenSize.SCREEN_HEIGHT)
}

struct DeviceType
{
    static let IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS      = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH < 568.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_5              = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 568.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_6_8            = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 667.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_6_8P           = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 736.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_X              = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 812.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_11_PRO         = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 812.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_12_13_MINI     = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 812.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_12             = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 844.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_12_PRO         = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 844.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_13             = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 844.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_XR_SMAX        = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 896.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_XS_MAX         = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 896.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_11             = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 896.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_11_PRO_MAX     = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 896.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_12_13_PRO_MAX  = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 926.0
    static let IS_IPAD                  = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad   && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 1024.0
    static let IS_IPAD_MINI_4           = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad   && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 1024.0
    static let IS_IPAD_PRO9             = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad   && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 1024.0
    static let IS_IPAD_10               = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad   && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 1080.0
    static let IS_IPAD_PRO10            = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad   && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 1112.0
    static let IS_IPAD_PRO11            = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad   && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 1194.0
    static let IS_IPAD_PRO12            = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad   && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 1366.0
    static let IS_IPAD_ALL              = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad
    
    static let IS_IPHONE_NOTCH_DEVICE = (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone) && (ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 896.0 || ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 812.0)
}

//struct DeviceDisplay
//{
//    static let isZoomed:Bool          = UIScreen.main.nativeScale >= UIScreen.main.scale
//}

struct Version{
    static let SYS_VERSION_FLOAT = (UIDevice.current.systemVersion as NSString).floatValue
    static let iOS9  = (Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT >=  9.0 && Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT < 10.0)
    static let iOS10 = (Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT >= 10.0 && Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT < 11.0)
    static let iOS11 = (Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT >= 11.0 && Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT < 12.0)
    static let iOS12 = (Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT >= 12.0 && Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT < 13.0)
    static let iOS13 = (Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT >= 13.0 && Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT < 14.0)
    static let iOS14 = (Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT >= 14.0 && Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT < 15.0)
    static let iOS15 = (Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT >= 15.0)
}

struct VersionAndNewer {
    static let iOS9 =  (Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT >=  9.0)
    static let iOS10 = (Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT >= 10.0)
    static let iOS11 = (Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT >= 11.0)
    static let iOS12 = (Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT >= 12.0)
    static let iOS13 = (Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT >= 13.0)
    static let iOS14 = (Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT >= 14.0)
    static let iOS15 = (Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT >= 15.0)
}
```

Update Xcode 11 / Swift 5.1:

```
enum UIUserInterfaceIdiom : Int
{
    case Unspecified
    case Phone
    case Pad
}

struct ScreenSize
{
    static let SCREEN_WIDTH         = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
    static let SCREEN_HEIGHT        = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
    static let SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH    = max(ScreenSize.SCREEN_WIDTH, ScreenSize.SCREEN_HEIGHT)
    static let SCREEN_MIN_LENGTH    = min(ScreenSize.SCREEN_WIDTH, ScreenSize.SCREEN_HEIGHT)
}

struct DeviceType
{
    static let IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS  = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH < 568.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_5          = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 568.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_6_8        = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 667.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_6_8P       = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 736.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_X          = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 812.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_11_PRO     = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 812.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_XR_SMAX    = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 896.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_XS_MAX     = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 896.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_11         = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 896.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_11_PRO_MAX = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 896.0
    static let IS_IPAD              = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 1024.0
    static let IS_IPAD_PRO10        = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 1112.0
    static let IS_IPAD_PRO12        = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 1366.0
    static let IS_IPAD_ALL          = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad
    
    static let IS_IPHONE_NOTCH_DEVICE = (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone) && (ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 896.0 || ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 812.0)
}

struct Version{
    static let SYS_VERSION_FLOAT = (UIDevice.current.systemVersion as NSString).floatValue
    static let iOS9 = (Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT >= 9.0 && Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT < 10.0)
    static let iOS10 = (Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT >= 10.0 && Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT < 11.0)
    static let iOS11 = (Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT >= 11.0 && Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT < 12.0)
    static let iOS12 = (Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT >= 12.0 && Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT < 13.0)
    static let iOS13 = (Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT >= 13.0)
}

struct VersionAndNewer {
    static let iOS9 = (Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT >= 9.0)
    static let iOS10 = (Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT >= 10.0)
    static let iOS11 = (Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT >= 11.0)
    static let iOS12 = (Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT >= 12.0)
    static let iOS13 = (Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT >= 13.0)
}
```

Hi i updated to Xcode10 / Swift 4.2 and the new sizes for IPhone XS / XSMAX /XR

with detection of Notch-IPhones.

Hope this helps someone.

```
enum UIUserInterfaceIdiom : Int
{
    case Unspecified
    case Phone
    case Pad
```

}

```
struct ScreenSize
{
    static let SCREEN_WIDTH         = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
    static let SCREEN_HEIGHT        = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
    static let SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH    = max(ScreenSize.SCREEN_WIDTH, ScreenSize.SCREEN_HEIGHT)
    static let SCREEN_MIN_LENGTH    = min(ScreenSize.SCREEN_WIDTH, ScreenSize.SCREEN_HEIGHT)
}

struct DeviceType
{
    static let IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS  = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH < 568.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_5          = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 568.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_6_8        = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 667.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_6_8P       = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 736.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_X          = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 812.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_XR_SMAX    = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 896.0
    static let IS_IPAD              = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 1024.0
    static let IS_IPAD_PRO10        = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 1112.0
    static let IS_IPAD_PRO12        = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 1366.0

    static let IS_IPHONE_NOTCH_DEVICE = (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone) && (ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 896.0 || ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 812.0)
}

struct Version{
    static let SYS_VERSION_FLOAT = (UIDevice.current.systemVersion as NSString).floatValue
    static let iOS9 = (Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT >= 9.0 && Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT < 10.0)
    static let iOS10 = (Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT >= 10.0 && Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT < 11.0)
    static let iOS11 = (Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT >= 11.0 && Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT < 12.0)
    static let iOS12 = (Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT >= 12.0)
}

struct VersionAndNewer {
    static let iOS9 = (Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT >= 9.0)
    static let iOS10 = (Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT >= 10.0)
    static let iOS11 = (Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT >= 11.0)
    static let iOS12 = (Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT >= 12.0)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the problem while migrating from an iOS 7 project to a iOS 8 project, since I didn't add a launch screen scene to my project.

In this case the screen size for iPhone 6 and 6+ are as iPhone 5.

See from apple documentation; [You use a launch XIB or storyboard file to indicate that your app runs on iPhone 6 Plus or iPhone 6.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
//Device Type enum
enum DeviceType: Int {

//Apple UnknownDevices
case UnknownDevice = 0

//Simulator
case Simulator

//Apple Air pods
case AppleAirPods

//Apple TV
case AppleTV2G
case AppleTV3G
case AppleTV4G
case AppleTV4K

//Apple Watch
case AppleWatch
case AppleWatchSeries1
case AppleWatchSeries2
case AppleWatchSeries3

//Apple Home Pods
case AppleHomePods

//Apple iPad
case AppleIpad
case AppleIpad2
case AppleIpad3
case AppleIpad4
case AppleIpadAir
case AppleIpadAir2
case AppleIpadPro_12_9
case AppleIpadPro_9_7
case AppleIpad5
case AppleIpadPro_12_9_Gen_2
case AppleIpadPro_10_5
case AppleIpadMini
case AppleIpadMini2
case AppleIpadMini3
case AppleIpadMini4

//Apple iPhone
case AppleIphone
case AppleIphone3G
case AppleIphone3GS
case AppleIphone4
case AppleIphone4S
case AppleIphone5
case AppleIphone5C
case AppleIphone5S
case AppleIphone6
case AppleIphone6P
case AppleIphone6S
case AppleIphone6SP
case AppleIphoneSE
case AppleIphone7
case AppleIphone7P
case AppleIphone8
case AppleIphone8P
case AppleIphoneX

//Apple iPod touch
case AppleIpodTouch
case AppleIpodTouch2G
case AppleIpodTouch3G
case AppleIpodTouch4G
case AppleIpodTouch5G
case AppleIpodTouch6G
}

// Method for device type
func getDeviceType() -> DeviceType{
    var systemInfo = utsname()
    uname(&systemInfo)
    let machineMirror = Mirror(reflecting: systemInfo.machine)
    let identifier = machineMirror.children.reduce("") { identifier, element in
        guard let value = element.value as? Int8, value != 0 else { return identifier }
        return identifier + String(UnicodeScalar(UInt8(value)))
    }

    switch identifier {

    //Simulator
    case "i386","x86_64": return .Simulator

    //Apple Air Pods
    case "AirPods1,1": return .AppleAirPods

    //Apple TV
    case "AppleTV2,1": return .AppleTV2G
    case "AppleTV3,1", "AppleTV3,2": return .AppleTV3G
    case "AppleTV5,3": return .AppleTV4G
    case "AppleTV6,2": return .AppleTV4K

    //Apple Watch
    case "Watch1,1", "Watch1,2": return .AppleWatch
    case "Watch2,6", "Watch2,7": return .AppleWatchSeries1
    case "Watch2,3", "Watch2,4": return .AppleWatchSeries2
    case "Watch3,1", "Watch3,2", "Watch3,3", "Watch3,4": return .AppleWatchSeries3

    // Apple HomePods
    case "AudioAccessory1,1": return .AppleHomePods

    //Apple iPad
    case "iPad1,1": return .AppleIpad
    case "iPad2,1", "iPad2,2", "iPad2,3", "iPad2,4": return .AppleIpad2
    case "iPad3,1", "iPad3,2", "iPad3,3": return .AppleIpad3
    case "iPad3,4", "iPad3,5", "iPad3,6": return .AppleIpad4
    case "iPad4,1", "iPad4,2", "iPad4,3": return .AppleIpadAir
    case "iPad5,3", "iPad5,4": return .AppleIpadAir2
    case "iPad6,7", "iPad6,8": return .AppleIpadPro_12_9
    case "iPad6,3", "iPad6,4": return .AppleIpadPro_9_7
    case "iPad6,11", "iPad6,12": return .AppleIpad5
    case "iPad7,1", "iPad7,2" : return .AppleIpadPro_12_9_Gen_2
    case "iPad7,3", "iPad7,4" : return .AppleIpadPro_10_5
    case "iPad2,5", "iPad2,6", "iPad2,7": return .AppleIpadMini
    case "iPad4,4", "iPad4,5", "iPad4,6": return .AppleIpadMini2
    case "iPad4,7", "iPad4,8", "iPad4,9": return .AppleIpadMini3
    case "iPad5,1", "iPad5,2": return .AppleIpadMini4

    //Apple iPhone
    case "iPhone1,1": return .AppleIphone
    case "iPhone1,2": return .AppleIphone3G
    case "iPhone2,1": return .AppleIphone3GS
    case "iPhone3,1", "iPhone3,2", "iPhone3,3": return .AppleIphone4
    case "iPhone4,1": return .AppleIphone4S
    case "iPhone5,1", "iPhone5,2": return .AppleIphone5
    case "iPhone5,3", "iPhone5,4": return .AppleIphone5C
    case "iPhone6,1", "iPhone6,2": return .AppleIphone5S
    case "iPhone7,2": return .AppleIphone6
    case "iPhone7,1": return .AppleIphone6P
    case "iPhone8,1": return .AppleIphone6S
    case "iPhone8,2": return .AppleIphone6SP
    case "iPhone8,4": return .AppleIphoneSE
    case "iPhone9,1", "iPhone9,3": return .AppleIphone7
    case "iPhone9,2", "iPhone9,4": return .AppleIphone7P
    case "iPhone10,1", "iPhone10,4": return .AppleIphone8
    case "iPhone10,2", "iPhone10,5": return .AppleIphone8P
    case "iPhone10,3", "iPhone10,6": return .AppleIphoneX

    //Apple iPod touch
    case "iPod1,1": return .AppleIpodTouch
    case "iPod2,1": return .AppleIpodTouch2G
    case "iPod3,1": return .AppleIpodTouch3G
    case "iPod4,1": return .AppleIpodTouch4G
    case "iPod5,1": return .AppleIpodTouch5G
    case "iPod7,1": return .AppleIpodTouch6G

    default:
        return .UnknownDevice
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For plus, you have to check zoom too

```
struct DeviceType
{
    static let IS_IPHONE = (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone)
    static let IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS =  UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH < 568.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_5 = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 568.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_6_7 = (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone) && (ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 667.0) && (UIScreen.main.nativeScale >= UIScreen.main.scale)
    private static let IS_STANDARD_IPHONE_6P_7P = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 736.0
    private static let IS_ZOOMED_IPHONE_6P_7P = (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone) && (ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 667.0) && (UIScreen.main.nativeScale < UIScreen.main.scale)
    static let IS_IPHONE_6P_7P = IS_STANDARD_IPHONE_6P_7P || IS_ZOOMED_IPHONE_6P_7P
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

public enum IADisplayType {
    // unknow device
    case        unspecified
    // iPhone
    case        unknowiPhone
    case        iPhone3GS
    case        iPhone4
    static let  iPhone4s            = iPhone5
    case        iPhone5
    static let  iPhone5s            = iPhone5
    static let  iPhoneSE            = iPhone5
    case        iPhone6
    case        iPhone6Plus
    static let  iPhone6s            = iPhone6
    static let  iPhone6sPlus        = iPhone6Plus
    static let  iPhone7             = iPhone6
    static let  iPhone7Plus         = iPhone6Plus
    static let  iPhone8             = iPhone6
    static let  iPhone8Plus         = iPhone6Plus
    case        iPhoneX
    // iPad
    case        unknowiPad
    case        iPad79
    static let  iPad97              = iPad79
    case        iPad105
    case        iPad129
    // Apple CarPlay
    case        carPlay
    // Apple TV
    case        tv
}

public final class IADisplayManager {

    // MARK: - public interface
    // singleton
    static var shared: IADisplayManager {
        get {
            return IADisplayManager()
        }
    }

    // get current device type
    public var currentType: IADisplayType {
        get {
            return calCurrentType()
        }
    }

    // device current Native Resolution
    public var nativeResolution: CGSize {
        get {
            return UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.size
        }
    }

    // device current Native Scale Factor
    public var nativeScaleFactor: CGFloat {
        get {
            return UIScreen.main.nativeScale
        }
    }

    // device current Interface Idiom
    public var interfaceIdiom: UIUserInterfaceIdiom {
        get {
            return UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom
        }
    }

    fileprivate init() {}

    // MARK: - private interface
    fileprivate func calCurrentType() -> IADisplayType {
        typealias Type = IADisplayType

        // unknown device
        if interfaceIdiom == .unspecified { return Type.unspecified }
        // iPhone && iPod Touch
        else if interfaceIdiom == .phone {
            if nativeScaleFactor == 1.0 && nativeResolution == CGSize(width: 320, height: 480) { return Type.iPhone3GS }
            else if nativeScaleFactor == 2.0 && nativeResolution == CGSize(width: 640, height: 960) { return Type.iPhone4 }
            else if nativeScaleFactor == 2.0 && nativeResolution == CGSize(width: 640, height: 1136) { return Type.iPhone5 }
            else if nativeScaleFactor == 2.0 && nativeResolution == CGSize(width: 750, height: 1334) { return Type.iPhone6 }
            else if (nativeScaleFactor-2.608) < 0.001 && nativeResolution == CGSize(width: 1080, height: 1920) { return Type.iPhone6Plus }
            else if nativeScaleFactor == 3.0 && nativeResolution == CGSize(width: 1125, height: 2436) { return Type.iPhoneX }
            else { return Type.unknowiPhone }
        }
        // iPad
        else if interfaceIdiom == .pad {
            if nativeScaleFactor == 2.0 && nativeResolution == CGSize(width: 1536, height: 2048) { return Type.iPad79 }
            else if nativeScaleFactor == 2.0 && nativeResolution == CGSize(width: 2224, height: 1668) { return Type.iPad105 }
            else if nativeScaleFactor == 2.0 && nativeResolution == CGSize(width: 2048, height: 2732) { return Type.iPad129 }
            else { return Type.unknowiPad }
        }
        // Apple CarPlay
        else if interfaceIdiom == .carPlay { return Type.carPlay }
        // Apple TV
        else if interfaceIdiom == .tv { return Type.tv }
        // unknown device
        else { return Type.unspecified }
    }

}
```