# Xcode, wrong storyboard is playing on device

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, device

I'm not using Auto Layout because I prefer to work with each device separately without those constraints. I have a separate storyboard for iPhone 5 and another for iPhone 6. I got the correct code in AppDelegate.m because on simulator the iPhone 5 storyboard loads on iPhone 5 simulator and iPhone 6 storyboard loads on iPhone6 simulator. On device, iPhone 5 storyboard loads on iPhone 5 device and iPhone 5 storyboards loads on iPhone 6 device but a zoomed version.

I used the following in code in application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in AppDelegate.m...

```
CGSize iosScreenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

if (iosScreenSize.height ==667) {

 UIStoryboard *iPhone6 =[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone6" bundle:nil];

 UIViewController *initialViewController =[iPhone6 instantiateInitialViewController];

 self.window.rootViewController = initialViewController;

 [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
 }
```

Why is the simulator loading the correct storyboard for iPhone 6 but the device loads the wrong storyboard, how can that even be??

Comment: It must work since when I comment this code, on iPhone 6 simulator, I receive a zoomed version of iPhone 5 storyboard. When I uncomment this code, I receive iPhone 5 storyboard on iPhone 5 and iPhone 6 storyboard on iPhone 6. But this is all in simulator.

Comment: Try deleting the app on the real device and reinstalling it.

Comment: I did that too. That changes nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Check the iphone model not the height in if condition
This may help you.
[iOS How to detect iPhone 6 plus, iPhone 6, iPhone 5 by macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25780283/ios-how-to-detect-iphone-6-plus-iphone-6-iphone-5-by-macro)

Comment: What do you mean by checking the iPhone model?

Comment: I posted the question link. Height didn't get proper iphone so it runs the iphone 5 storyboard on iphone 6