# iPhone 6s Plus size screen getting cut off on iPhone 6 Plus

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-storyboard

I have a storyboard I am building for an iPhone 6 Plus and iPhone 6s application. For some reason, when I run the application on the iPhone 6 Plus the screen is cut off but on the 6s Plus everything fits on the screen. Is the screen size different? Also, is there a way to find out what if the user is using an iPhone 6s or 6 Plus?

Comment: Is it possible to add screenshots to your question? Also, have you tested this on both devices, or just on the simulators?

Comment: @DanielStorm I tested it in the simulator for iPhone 6 and 6s Plus and everything fit. Just when I tested it on a iPhone 6 device it did not fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use Auto Layout

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/

Debug your screen with

```
po [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]
```

Check if user is using an iPhone 6 or 6 Plus

[iOS How to detect iPhone 6 plus, iPhone 6, iPhone 5 by macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25780283/ios-how-to-detect-iphone-6-plus-iphone-6-iphone-5-by-macro)

Comment: the problem was the screen on the iPhone 6 was zoomed in. The last link helped me find the answer