# Detect iphone 5 4" screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect iPhone 5 (widescreen devices)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446990/how-to-detect-iphone-5-widescreen-devices)

Is there a way I can detect if the current device is the iphone 5? More specifically if it's using the new 4" screen?

Comment: u can use `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]` right?

Comment: If he is not optimized for iPhone5 screen, then it will still output 320x480

Comment: You shouldn't have different views based on the screen. More here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446990/how-to-detect-iphone-5-widescreen-devices

Comment: I don't... there's just 1 case where I need to resize the tableview cells to different screen heights... before it was just an ipad an iphone but now I have to detect the ipohone 5's taller screen :)

Comment: It is a duplicate. And I really like the answer from that question.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52821290/3472073

Answer (score 44):

Use this

```
#define IS_IPHONE5 (([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-568)?NO:YES)
```

Answer (score 17):

I think you should concentrate on preferred display mode, rather than detecting iPhone5. Who knows what devices Apple will manufacture, but if your software supports that mode, it will be futureproof.

```
BOOL isiPhone5 = CGSizeEqualToSize([[UIScreen mainScreen] preferredMode].size,CGSizeMake(640, 1136));
```

In the future, folks might want to change preferred display mode on the fly. For example disconnect AppleTV from 720p tv and plug to 1080p, without restarting the app of course.

Comment: Make sure that you have the `Default-568h@2x.png` set as the launch image or it won't know to use the new size as the [UIScreen mainScreen]

Comment: @mkral mode is measured in pixels, not points

Comment: yea I didn't see/know about that. Tested it and you're right.

Comment: note that UIScreen preferredMode is available from iOS 4.3. To get the screen size on iOS < 4.3 use this: CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        CGFloat screenScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
        CGSize screenSize = CGSizeMake(screenBounds.size.width * screenScale, screenBounds.size.height * screenScale);

Comment: @blejzz The inquiry was about iPhone 5, which came with iOS 6 preinstalled.

Comment: @bioffe Yes but if you have a universal app you have to consider that also.

Answer (score 4):

### Add this code in your initializtion:

```
if([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
     if(UIScreenOverscanCompensationScale==1136/640){
             //move to your iphone5 storyboard
             [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:(NSString *) bundle (NSBundle *)];
  }
     else{
             //move to your iphone4s storyboard
             [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:(NSString *) bundle (NSBundle *)];
  }
}
```

This was an answer posted by me in another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12516986/iphone-5-4-inch/12518141#12518141).

Comment: The above approach forces you to create two separate sets of views, which could be a real pain for the sake of consistency.  If your UI changes aren't drastic, I'd really recommend just testing for the size of the screen and then resizing and potentially repositioning your objects programmatically.

Comment: doing that allows you to take full advantage of the bigger screen, yes you could just stretch/shrink it, but this will work. Also the overscanCompensationScale if statement works

Comment: I definitely agree. Just making the point that auto-resizing UI elements that should be consistent on both devices now have to be created twice with the above approach.

Answer (score 2):

Add this code to your application:

```
if ([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2.f && screenHeight == 568.0f)
    {// iPhone 5 code}
else
    {// previous version code}
```

Comment: You forgot to add how to get screenHeight ;-)