# How to detect if the device is an iPhone 5?

Tags: ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect iPhone 5 (widescreen devices)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446990/how-to-detect-iphone-5-widescreen-devices)

I am trying to add a new view to an existing ios4 project to handle the new iphone5 screen size.

However I dont have an iphone here to test on and the code I am using to test the screen size isnt working, just wondering if there is another way of detecting the device type??

```
NSLog(@"%f", [ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height);

if([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568.0)
    {
        //move to your iphone5 storyboard
        [self changeView:splashScreenBIGV viewH:splashScreenH animLength:SCREEN_CHANGE_ANIM_LENGTH];
   }
    else{
        //move to your iphone4s storyboard
        [self changeView:splashScreenV viewH:splashScreenH animLength:SCREEN_CHANGE_ANIM_LENGTH];            
    }
}
```

Comment: Try [an earlier answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446990/how-to-detect-iphone-5-widescreen-devices).

Comment: Ditto @RichardAltenburg-Brainchild - the reality of life is sometimes you need a quick fix. Moving to the constraint layout system is the long term correct approach but will take you some time if you have many views.

Comment: Using my post here the optimization code for universal app iPhone 3Gs/4s/5 and iPad http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution/17379460#17379460

Answer (score 60):

For my universal app, [Forex App](http://itunes.apple.com/app/forex-app/id527137098?mt=8), I'm simply using the screen height detection concept like so:

```
CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    if (screenSize.height > 480.0f) {
        /*Do iPhone 5 stuff here.*/
    } else {
        /*Do iPhone Classic stuff here.*/
    }
} else {
    /*Do iPad stuff here.*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12447113/300292). Basically, you don't. Use the new constraint layout system in iOS 6. You'll be chasing your tail if you have to rev your layout for every new device with a different screen size/resolution.

Comment: ok, I get what you are saying, I dont want to create new xib files for every screen that I have. So do I recreate all the screens as iphone5 screens? will it just shrink them for the older devices?

Comment: The OP also said an existing iOS 4 project. maybe he doesn't want or need to go to iOS 6 yet