# How to support multiple resolutions in MonoTouch

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

What is the approach to support different resolutions on MonoTouch. I just created a new XIB in the latest version of MonoTouch.  When I run it, it is iPhone 4 resolution.

My simulator is iPhone5 and so I see black bars in top and bottom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off all you must provide [default (launch) image for iPhone 5](http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/launchImages.html).

Possible solutions

- Use the auto-resizing capabilities of iOS (View.AutoresizingMask)
- [Detect iPhone 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604944/how-to-detect-if-the-device-is-an-iphone-5) and load different xib like in universal apps. Read more about this great in tutorial [Building MonoTouch Applications that run on both the iPad and iPhone Getting Started](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/Guides/Getting_Started/Hello%2C_iPad___Universal_Apps) from Xamarin Developer Center!

Comment: The article states --> "Note that the Default-568h@2x.png image is required for an app to display in full-screen mode on the iPhone 5."  Seriously??  This is the only way to have your app use the full screen of the iPhone?  Weird.  Am I correct in assuming this?

Comment: Actually, if it forces developers to use the default image instead of a blank screen then having this requirements makes apps general in better :)  I suppose...