# How do you use isWidescreenEnabled()?

Tags: kobold2d

In the [release notes of Kobold2D v2.0.4](http://kobold2d.com/display/KKDOC/Kobold2D+Release+Notes), it says:

> added C function isWidescreenEnabled() to report if app is running on
>   a widescreen device with widescreen "enabled" (ie when
>   Default-568h@2x.png is included in the project)

What do I need to do in order to use the isWidescreenEnabled function, other than installing Xcode 4.5 and Kobold2D v2.0.4, and including Default-568h@2x.png in the project?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use isWidescreenEnabled().  You could just use winSize and look for a height of 568 (for portrait UI; for a landscape UI, look for a width of 568).  Here's some sample code (for a portrait UI):

```
CGSize screenSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
if (screenSize.height == 568) {
  // You have a device with a 4" retina display; do something special
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use isWideScreenEnabled like so:

```
if (isWideScreenEnabled())
{
    // widescreen-specific code here ...
}
```

It doesn't require Xcode 4.5 or the Default-568h@2x.png. It's based on the answers and comments in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446990/how-to-detect-iphone-5-widescreen-devices).

Comment: I tried that, but I get an error, "Use of undeclared identifier 'isWideScreenEnabled'"