# Best way to detect the device is iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, iphone-5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect iPhone 5 (widescreen devices)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446990/how-to-detect-iphone-5-widescreen-devices)

Does anybody know a better way to detect whether the device is an iPhone 5 than checking the screen height?

```
[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568.0;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think can help you this: [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446990/how-to-detect-iphone-5-widescreen-devices/12447113#12447113

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use the following macro:

```
#define IS_IPHONE ( [[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] isEqualToString:@"iPhone"] )
#define IS_HEIGHT_GTE_568 [[UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds].size.height >= 568.0f
#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( IS_IPHONE && IS_HEIGHT_GTE_568 )
```

And then i can do:

```
if(IS_IPHONE_5)
{
    NSLog(@"i am an iPhone 5!");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"This is not an iPhone 5");
}
```

Comment: Does that also not produce a positive for the in development super secret iPhone that only I know about that has a 721 pixel high screen?  (The iPhone II)

Comment: Possibly yes, you can alway's adapt the IS_HEIGHT_GTE_568 if you don't like that. Up to you to test... let us know..

Comment: you are in wrong