# How can I check what iOS device the user is using?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

How can I find out what device a user is using? The code I currently use is:

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
if(screenBounds.size.height == 568){
    NSLog(@"User is using an iPhone 5s, 5c, or 5");
}
else{
    NSLog(@"User is using an iPhone 4s or earlier");
}
```

What other numbers could this return, and what device would it be? For example, I was hoping for something like this:

`screenBounds.size.height == 568` would be an iPhone5/5s/5c
`screenBounds.size.height == 480` would be an iPhone 4/5s
`screenBounds.size.height > 570` would be an iPad

and so on. I'm going to be using this to change the `nib` file based on what device the user is using, so that I won't have to move every single button, image, label, or anything else with `CGRectMake`.

I'm not using auto layout because I would also like to have some more customization based on what device the user is using.

Comment: I'm not seeing what you're looking for beyond the three heights you already have.

Comment: @Kevin That is not a proper duplicate - it's the wrong question.

Comment: @Domenico - please stop adding the `xcode` tag. It is not relevant to your question. Read the description of the tag.

Comment: @rmaddy sorry, my bad - I replaced it with `cocoa-touch`

Comment: @Domenico instead of editing this question with a new problem you should ask a whole new question.

Comment: @rmaddy sorry.. I will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check the kind of device:

```
if ( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad )
{
// You are using iPad
    return YES; 
}

else if ( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomiPhone )
{
  CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

 if(screenBounds.size.height == 568){
    NSLog(@"User is using an iPhone 5+");

} else{
    NSLog(@"User is using an iPhone 4s-");
}
}
```

Comment: I still need to know iPad mini and things like that, though

Comment: Well, I didn't do anything with iPad mini screen size yet, but I was looking for something about it and found the answer here: [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366976/is-it-possible-to-detect-that-your-ios-app-is-running-on-an-ipad-mini-at-runtime). I hope this is what you are looking for. Good luck :)

Comment: @Domenico The iPad mini is no different than the other iPads. It's the same screen resolution. It's just physically smaller. Use the same nib for any iPad or iPad mini.