# How do I create an if statement like the one below for iPad screen size?

Tags: ios, ipad, sprite-kit, height, screen-size

I am trying to create a universal app, and I am just wondering how I write the following code to direct it to iPad version of app. Specifically what should the navtiveBounds.height be for the iPad Air and Mini.
Thanks So Much :)

```
if UIScreen.mainScreen().nativeBounds.height == 2208 {
            println("iPhone 6+")
            let delay = SKAction.waitForDuration(1)
            let transition = SKAction.runBlock({
                let scene = Menu6Plus(size: self.size)
                self.view?.presentScene(scene)
            })

            runAction(SKAction.sequence([delay, transition]))


        }
```

Comment: Instead of posting a question like this, why not simply run your app on an iPad (real or simulated) and see what value you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    // Code for iPad!
}
```

Also, I believe that if you were to use the nativeBounds property to determine screen size, iPad and iPad mini would both return the same 1024-by-768 resolution.
If you really need to detect if the user is running an iPad Mini at runtime, try this:

[Is it possible to detect that your iOS app is running on an iPad mini at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366976/is-it-possible-to-detect-that-your-ios-app-is-running-on-an-ipad-mini-at-runtime)