# How can I get to know that my program is running on iPhone 5?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have a `UIViewController` Class with Interface which I want it to be different when it's running on iPhone-5, how can get the iPhone type in my code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect iPhone 5 (widescreen devices)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446990/how-to-detect-iphone-5-widescreen-devices)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use following code to check its iphone 5 or not.
first define following code in .m file.

```
 #define IS_IPHONE_5 ( [ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height == 568 )
```

then use following condition

```
 if( IS_IPHONE_5 )
{
   // Running in iphone 5
}
 else
 {
   // Running in other iphone
 }
```

Comment: Am I right about the number? 548 is correct,

Comment: No, iphone 5 has screen size of 568.

Comment: I'm confused with this size. In IB when I choose 4inch display, the display size is 320*548. But when I run my program on simulator, my buttons don't appear at the same place where I put them in to my view.

Comment: because your simulator is run in 480 size. you have to choose 4inch ratina display from simulator settings--> hardware--> device-->
Then you can see whole screen

Comment: My simulator is in 4inch mode, I tried to post my screenshots, but because my reputation is under 10,(I'm a newbie here:) ) stackoverflow don't allow me. All my buttons in my view are custom buttons, they're positions have little difference in simulator compare to what is in IB view.

Answer (score 2):

You just set the following code in AppDelegate...

```
int deviceType;

float height = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;

    if (height==568) {
        self.deviceType = 5;
    }
    else
    {
        self.deviceType = 4;
    }
```

Following code you want to use any where in xcode classes

```
if(appdelegate.deviceType == 5){
    iPhone 5 Code...
}
else{
    iPhone 4 code
}
```