# How to know if the user's iPhone is iPhone 4 or iPhone 5?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, device, screen-size

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect iPhone 5 (widescreen devices)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446990/how-to-detect-iphone-5-widescreen-devices)

I would to know if there is a simple method to know if the device is iPhone 4 or iPhone 5 ? Maybe there is a global variable that stocks this information ? I would like to do something like this :

```
 if (device == iphone 5){
 frame.size = 300px;
 }
 else if (device == iphone 4){
 frame.size =  200px;
 }
```

Just a very simple example.

Comment: Yes and no. As you can see in the link you gave me, they discuss about severals methods, whereas I just posted my case and had a perfect good answer. See NANNAV's answer :)

Comment: You mean the answer copied verbatim from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12587966/64976)?

Comment: NANNAV could have added the answer there and avoided polluting SO with duplicate questions and answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] localizedModel]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
     CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    if (screenBounds.size.height == 568)
 {
    //For iPhone5
 }

else
{
   //for iPhone4 and all other

}
```