# Distinguishing between iPhone 4 vs 5

Tags: iphone, media-queries

What media queries do I need to use if I want to distinguish between the iPhone 4 and the iPhone 5?  (I need to distinguish between vertical and horizontal as well)

Update: Someone has given me a query for *just* the iPhone 5, but I am looking for 4 different ones that will effect only the iPhone and phones of the exact same size.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect iPhone 5 (widescreen devices)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446990/how-to-detect-iphone-5-widescreen-devices)

Answer (score 0):

Because of the longer screen, the max-device-width is different on an iPhone 5.

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 640px) and (max-device-width: 1136px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    /* iPhone 5 specific stuff */
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for something a little more specific than just 1 type of phone.  I have some general mobile rules already, so I want to make sure this targets JUST the iPhone 5 in portrait mode, JUST the iphone 5 in landscape mode, etc.

Comment: You'll need more than media queries (which was the scope of your question), then. Nothing stops someone from making a phone with the same pixel dimensions and density as an iPhone 5. As for portrait vs. landscape, there are media queries for that.

Comment: I was able to do it with the iPad by being very specific with miniumum size, maximum size, etc.  It's okay if it effects another phone with the exact same dimensions, I just don't want something that will impact all mobile devices.