# Migrating my app to iPhone 5 resolution

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, iphone-5

I am migrating my app to iphone app to iPhone 5 resolution. I have seen from other questions in stackoverflow stating this:

Example:

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
if (screenBounds.size.height == 568) {
    // code for 4-inch screen
} else {
    // code for 3.5-inch screen
}
```

But it seems that, I need to add this code for all my images. Is there a simpler way? meaning a more generic way.

Thanks...

Comment: yes, I confirm you it is that simple.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect iPhone 5 (widescreen devices)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446990/how-to-detect-iphone-5-widescreen-devices)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to develop or migrate apps for iPhone 5 screen resolution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution)

Answer (score 0):

Create a category for UIImage class.
Move this logic to UIImage class.

Now change the existing UIImage creation function with the one which you have created in the category.

Comment: give an example of it.. please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use AutoLayout if you are a registered Apple Developer I recommend the tutorials you can find from last year's WWDC.

Comment: It will not support OS < 6.0

Comment: Ok then AutoLayout is not an option. Sorry

Comment: @Apurv - iOS6 appears to have about 80%+ adoption at this point

Comment: @skinnyTOD, 20% is still a lot (millions), most of them are iPad 1 that can't be updated

Answer (score 0):

Check with writing this in `prefix.h` file

```
#define IPHONE5 ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )
```

and whenever you want to check, Just check

```
if (IPHONE 5) {
     // Code for iPhone 5 Device
      enter code here
} else if (!IPHONE5) {
    // Code for 3.5 inch (iphone 4 nad less)
     enter code here
}
```

Comment: And what if the device orientation is landscape?

Comment: Should inform you about iPhone 5 in landscape mode too

Answer (score 0):

Build an app using iOS 6 as the Base SDK and use the Auto Layout feature to make screens that can scale for all type of screens. You'll need Xcode 4.5 to do this. Add a splash image named `Default-568h@2x.png`

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations

    switch (interfaceOrientation) {

        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            //[self ArrangeControllsFor_Protrate];
            [self performSelector:@selector(ArrangeControllsFor_Protrate) withObject:Nil afterDelay:0.005f];
            return YES;
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            [self performSelector:@selector(ArrangeControllsFor_LandScape) withObject:Nil afterDelay:0.005f];
            return YES;
            break;
    }
}
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{

    switch (toInterfaceOrientation){

        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            [self performSelector:@selector(ArrangeControllsFor_Protrate) withObject:Nil afterDelay:0.005f];
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            [self performSelector:@selector(ArrangeControllsFor_LandScape) withObject:Nil afterDelay:0.005f];
            break;
    }
}
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{

    return YES;
}
-(void)ArrangeControllsFor_Protrate{

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
    [self.view setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320,568)];
    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)];
}

-(void)ArrangeControllsFor_LandScape{

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
    [self.view setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 568, 320)];
    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,  568, 320)];
}
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    UIInterfaceOrientation statusBarOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(statusBarOrientation))
    {
        [self ArrangeControllsFor_Protrate];
    }
    else
    {
        [self ArrangeControllsFor_LandScape];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is for supporting the orientation and to set views and contents accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

1. First you have to create a launch image with dimensions 640 x 1136 and retina quality.
2. Then name the image as Default-568h@2x.png and set it as launch image in your iphone application.
3. Then you will have to set auto resizing mask.
4. Create all the required images that you want to be compatible with iPhone 5 screen resolution.
5. Run your app in your iPhone 5, everything should work as required.