# Simulator does not show me iPhone5 real size?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying on xcode to run our app on the simulator and check the screen height.
I am using cocos2d, but i also have tried apple methods .

```
     NSLog(@"HEIGT:%f",[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height);

      //and also :
     winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
     NSLog(@"HEIGT:%f",winSize.Height);
```

both gives me height of 480 on the iPhone5 4 inch simulation .
Why is that ? and how can i know if this is actually iPhone5 ?

Comment: have you added iphone 5 splash? - Default-568h@2x.png ?

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446990/how-to-detect-iphone-5-widescreen-devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few days ago, I faced same problem and solution is....

set Launch Image for Retina (4-inch) with proper size.

[image]

Comment: thanks that worked . but what if i dont want to put a default image on loading ?

Comment: if you can not add default image then black screen is appear at loading time for few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

In your project, take one image of having size 640*1136 and add to Retina image of launch images and you will actual size. You can check in print log also.

```
2013-04-22 13:10:56.510 test[7526:c07] cocos2d: cocos2d v1.0.1
2013-04-22 13:10:56.511 test[7526:c07] cocos2d: Using Director Type:CCDirectorDisplayLink
2013-04-22 13:10:56.654 test[7526:c07] cocos2d: OS version: 6.1 (0x06010000)
2013-04-22 13:10:56.654 test[7526:c07] cocos2d: GL_VENDOR:   Apple Computer, Inc.
2013-04-22 13:10:56.655 test[7526:c07] cocos2d: GL_RENDERER: Apple Software Renderer
2013-04-22 13:10:56.655 test[7526:c07] cocos2d: GL_VERSION:  OpenGL ES-CM 1.1 APPLE
2013-04-22 13:10:56.655 test[7526:c07] cocos2d: GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 4096
2013-04-22 13:10:56.656 test[7526:c07] cocos2d: GL_MAX_MODELVIEW_STACK_DEPTH: 16
2013-04-22 13:10:56.656 test[7526:c07] cocos2d: GL_MAX_SAMPLES: 4
2013-04-22 13:10:56.657 test[7526:c07] cocos2d: GL supports PVRTC: YES
2013-04-22 13:10:56.657 test[7526:c07] cocos2d: GL supports BGRA8888 textures: YES
2013-04-22 13:10:56.657 test[7526:c07] cocos2d: GL supports NPOT textures: YES
2013-04-22 13:10:56.658 test[7526:c07] cocos2d: GL supports discard_framebuffer: YES
2013-04-22 13:10:56.658 test[7526:c07] cocos2d: compiled with NPOT support: NO
2013-04-22 13:10:56.658 test[7526:c07] cocos2d: compiled with VBO support in TextureAtlas : YES
2013-04-22 13:10:56.659 test[7526:c07] cocos2d: compiled with Affine Matrix transformation in CCNode : YES
2013-04-22 13:10:56.659 test[7526:c07] cocos2d: compiled with Profiling Support: NO
2013-04-22 13:10:56.708 test[7526:c07] cocos2d: Frame interval: 1
2013-04-22 13:10:56.709 test[7526:c07] Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
2013-04-22 13:10:56.709 test[7526:c07] cocos2d: surface size: 320x568
```

this is working fine for me.