# iOS Writing Macro detect 3.5 inch or 4 inch display

Tags: ios, objective-c, macros, c-preprocessor

I am trying to write a macro to determine the device is 3.5 inch or 4 inch. Some thing similar below.

```
    #define IOS_OLDER_THAN_6 ( [ [ [ UIDevice currentDevice ] systemVersion ] floatValue ] < 6.0 )
    #define IOS_NEWER_OR_EQUAL_TO_6 ( [ [ [ UIDevice currentDevice ] systemVersion ] floatValue ] >= 6.0 )
```

Can someone help me. Please

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52821290/3472073

Answer (score 56, accepted):

you can detect iphopne 3.5 inch or 4 inch using bellow:-

```
#define isiPhone5  ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)?TRUE:FALSE
```

you can check it using bellow method for example:-

```
     if (isiPhone5)
     {
           // this is iphone 4 inch
     }
     else
     {

           //Iphone  3.5 inch
     }
```

**Please take a look of this link for you knew all about Macro for determine the device is 3.5 inch or 4 inch.**

[How to detect iPhone 5 (widescreen devices)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446990/how-to-detect-iphone-5-widescreen-devices)

Comment: This macro is incorrect. For code: max = IS_iPhone5 ? 5 : 6; I receive 1 bacause you forgot to add bracers. Shorthand if-else format is uneccessary here. Below correct code:
#define isiPhone5  ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)

Comment: isn't bound orientation oriented in iOS8 ?

Comment: @SjoerdPerfors you're right. I added a check to the orientation in an answer I posted on another question since answers aren't accepted on this question anymore: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35208438/159758

Answer (score 5):

Mean something like this:

```
#define IS_IPHONE5 (([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-568)?NO:YES)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can check if it is iphone 5 (4 inch) like this:

The iPhone 5's screen has a height of 568.

```
if ([ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height == 568)
```