# How can I detect if my device is an iPhoneX in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone-x

I am sure there is a better, more proper way to do this. But right now I am using UIScreen.main.bounds to detect if I am dealing with an iPhone X (812 tall) or not. This specific app is landscape only, btw. So this is what I have in this function where I am crating slides for a slide view:

```
func setupSlideViews(slideView: [SlideView]) {
    let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds

    var frame: CGRect!
    if screenSize.width == 812 {
        frame = scrollView.frame
    } else {
        frame = view.frame
    }
    scrollView.frame = frame
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: frame.width * CGFloat(slideViews.count), height: frame.height)

    for (i, slideView) in slideViews.enumerated() {
        slideView.frame = CGRect(x: frame.width * CGFloat(i), y: 0, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
        scrollView.addSubview(slideView)
    }
}
```

But how do you check for the model?

Comment: take a look please https://stackoverflow.com/a/52821290/3472073

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you need to detect if a device is iPhoneX don't use `bounds`, it depends on the orientation of the device. So if the user opens your app in portrait mode it will fail. You can use Device property `nativeBounds` which doesn't change on rotation.

> In iOS 8 and later, a screen’s bounds property takes the interface
>   orientation of the screen into account. This behavior means that the
>   bounds for a device in a portrait orientation may not be the same as
>   the bounds for the device in a landscape orientation. Apps that rely
>   on the screen dimensions can use the object in the
>   fixedCoordinateSpace property as a fixed point of reference for any
>   calculations they must make. (Prior to iOS 8, a screen’s bounds
>   rectangle always reflected the screen dimensions relative to a
>   portrait-up orientation. Rotating the device to a landscape or
>   upside-down orientation did not change the bounds.)

```
extension UIDevice {
    var iPhoneX: Bool {
        return UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height == 2436
    }
}
```

---

usage

```
if UIDevice.current.iPhoneX { 
    print("This device is a iPhoneX")
}
```

Comment: simple and effective! thanks

Comment: @tylerSF you are welcome

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52821290/3472073