# Using different arrays for different iPhones

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have each of those images set in an array that calls out to Firebase for the image. I was wondering if I could have a separate array to call from for different sized iPhones because the iPhone X screen size cuts some of the text off. I want to resize the images for just the iPhone X. Is there a way to see what device the user has and then if it is the iPhone X it would show array1, and if was anything else it would show array2. I have tried looking at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197509/how-to-get-device-make-and-model-on-ios) however what they did is too complicated and not what I am looking for. What I am trying to do I know is very simple. I am just not sure the direct code for it. I just need to know if it's an iPhone X then switch to array1, otherwise I don't care which device it is wether it's an iPad with cellular or wifi. Just check if the device is an iPhone X otherwise just keep everything the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get device make and model on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197509/how-to-get-device-make-and-model-on-ios)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I have just cleared up my question incase that helps you better understand it. Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect if the device is iPhone X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46192280/detect-if-the-device-is-iphone-x).

Comment: The concept is the same. Check the device model and do what you need to do. Definitely a duplicate, sorry!

Comment: How if it is not what I  am looking for? How many times do I have to say that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you should know about a model of a iPhone.
You should know about a screen/view ratio (width / height).
Ratio is a main reason to decide what images you should use.

You can find screen ratio with [bounds](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscreen/1617838-bounds) property, for example:

```
if (CGRectGetWidth([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds) / CGRectGetHeight([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds) <= GOOD_VALUE){
//use one
}
else
{
   //use other
}
```

Also screen has a property [scale](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscreen/1617836-scale), that will be very useful for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I will check this out tomorrow as it is getting late here, and will get bak to you tomorrow.

Comment: What is the <= GOOD_VAUE?

Comment: Rather than the <= GOOD_VALUE, is that where I would put in the screen ratio value or what value do I put there? Thank you so much for helping me!

Comment: I changed it to: let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds  let screenWidth = screenSize.width  let screenHeight = screenSize.height                                      if screenWidth / screenHeight == 125/2436 ...