# safeAreaInsets in UIView is 0 on an iPhone X

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, iphone-x

I am updating my app to adapt it for iPhone X. All views work fine by now except one. I have a view controller that presents a custom UIView that covers the whole screen. Before I was using `UIScreen.main.bounds` to find out the size of the view before all layout was done (I need it for putting the correct itemSize for a collectionView). I thought that now I could do something like
 `UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - safeAreaInsets.bottom` to get the right usable size. The problem is, safeAreaInsets returns (0,0,0,0) trying on an iPhone X (Simulator). Any ideas? In other views, I get the right numbers for safeAreaInsets.

Thank you!

Comment: Anywhere, anytime, you can use: `    if #available(iOS 11.0, tvOS 11.0, *) {
        return UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.safeAreaInsets != .zero
    }
    return false` [SOURCE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47067296/1033581)

Comment: As per Mars answer below, I'm also seeing that the only reliable way to get these is in viewDidLayoutSubviews() or viewDidAppear. Actually, "override func viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange()" seems to work best.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I already figure out the solution: I was doing all the implementation in the `init` of the view. safeAreaInsets has the correct size in `layoutSubviews()`

Comment: If you're using `view` in a `UIViewController`, you can also do it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` and it should work as it did for me.

Comment: Be aware of being on viewWillLayoutSubviews subviews have wrong saveAreaInsets value.

Comment: You can also do it in UIViewController.viewDidLayoutSubviews.

Answer (score 106):

I recently had a similar problem where the safe area insets are returning (0, 0, 0, 0) as soon as viewDidLoad is triggered. It seems that they are set fractionally later than the rest of the view loading.

I got round it by overriding **viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange** and doing my layout in that instead:

```
override func viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange() {
 // ... your layout code here
}
```

Comment: ditto - this is correct - despite it being a bit dumb that this is the case

Comment: If the OP wants to do this in the custom view instead of the view controller, then there's also the UIView method **safeAreaInsetsDidChange**.

Comment: This is perfect if you're configuring your cells in a viewcontroller

Comment: I've changed to landscape mode and this is the only answer that worked for me!

Comment: Works like a charm. Not sure how I even survived the past 5 years not knowing about this method :/

Answer (score 43):

I've run into this issue too trying to move up views to make way for the keyboard on the iPhone X. The safeAreaInsets of the main view are always 0, even though I know the subviews have been laid out at this point as the screen has been drawn. A work around I found, as and mentioned above, is to get the keyWindow and check its safe area insets instead.

Obj-C:

```
CGFloat bottomInset = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.safeAreaInsets.bottom;
```

Swift:

```
let bottomInset = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets.bottom
```

You can then use this value to adjust constraints or view frames as required.

Comment: It works on portrait mode. The landscape doesn't have the view on top.

Comment: only this solution worked for me. viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange() not called sometimes at all.

Comment: Where do I add `bottomInset` then?

Answer (score 21):

I have a view which is a subview inside another view.
I found that I can't get safeAreaInsets correctly, it always return 0, in that view on iPhoneX even if I put it in layoutSubviews.
The final solution is I use following UIScreen extension to detect safeAreaInsets which can work like a charm.

```
extension UIScreen {

    func widthOfSafeArea() -> CGFloat {

        guard let rootView = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow else { return 0 }

        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {

            let leftInset = rootView.safeAreaInsets.left

            let rightInset = rootView.safeAreaInsets.right

            return rootView.bounds.width - leftInset - rightInset

        } else {

            return rootView.bounds.width

        }

    }

    func heightOfSafeArea() -> CGFloat {

        guard let rootView = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow else { return 0 }

        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {

            let topInset = rootView.safeAreaInsets.top

            let bottomInset = rootView.safeAreaInsets.bottom

            return rootView.bounds.height - topInset - bottomInset

        } else {

            return rootView.bounds.height

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have already edited my answer.

Comment: I found that when manually adding subviews (even if they use autolayout), in some cases, like table view controllers, `safeAreaInsets` is always zero. Using the application key window returns the correct safe area insets. Good call.

Comment: This doesn't work on iOS 11 when there is just a status bar (iPhone 6,7,...). It will return 0 for the top inset height

Comment: You could make them static

Answer (score 15):

I try to use "self.view.safeAreaInset" in a view controller. First, it is a NSInsetZero when I use it in the controller's life cycle method "viewDidLoad", then I search it from the net and get the right answer, the log is like:

```
ViewController loadView() SafeAreaInsets :UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
ViewController viewDidLoad() SafeAreaInsets :UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
ViewController viewWillAppear() SafeAreaInsets :UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
ViewController viewDidLayoutSubviews() SafeAreaInsets :UIEdgeInsets(top: 44.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 34.0, right: 0.0)
ViewController viewDidAppear() SafeAreaInsets :UIEdgeInsets(top: 44.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 34.0, right: 0.0)
```

so you can choice the right method that you need the safeAreaInset and use it!

Answer (score 9):

**Swift iOS 11,12,13+**

```
var insets : UIEdgeInsets = .zero

 override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

     insets = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.safeAreaInsets ?? .zero
     //Or you can use this
     insets = self.view.safeAreaInsets
}
```

Comment: Do we know why UIApplication.shared.keyWindow stopped returning the safe area insets? Seems risky to use UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.safeAreaInsets if we can't be sure this will continue to work into the future. I am assuming this is because of the addition of the Scenes, but they didn't appear until iOS 13 so maybe not?

Answer (score 4):

In my case I was adding a UICollectionView inside viewDidLoad()

```
collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame, collectionViewLayout: createCompositionalLayout())
```

Unfortunately at this stage safeAreaLayoutGuide is still zero.

I solved it by adding:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    collectionView.frame = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame
}
```

Answer (score 2):

the viewDidAppear(_:) method of the container view controller that extends the safe area of its embedded child view controller to account for the views in .

Make your modifications in this method because the safe area insets for a view are not accurate until the view is added to a view hierarchy.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

   if (@available(iOS 11, *)) {

     var newSafeArea = view.safeAreaInsets

     // Adjust the safe area to accommodate 
     //  the width of the side view.

     if let sideViewWidth = sideView?.bounds.size.width {
        newSafeArea.right += sideViewWidth
     }

    // Adjust the safe area to accommodate 
    //  the height of the bottom view.
    if let bottomViewHeight = bottomView?.bounds.size.height {
       newSafeArea.bottom += bottomViewHeight
    }

    // Adjust the safe area insets of the 
    //  embedded child view controller.
    let child = self.childViewControllers[0]
    child.additionalSafeAreaInsets = newSafeArea
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've come across the same problem. In my case the view I'm inserting would be sized correctly after calling `view.layoutIfNeeded()`. The `view.safeAreaInsets` was set after this, but only the `top` value was correct. The bottom value was still `0` (this on an iPhone X).

While trying to figure out at what point the `safeAreaInsets` are set correctly, I've added a breakpoint on the view's `safeAreaInsetsDidChange()` method. This was being called multiple times, but only when I saw `CALayer.layoutSublayers()` in the backtrace the value had been set correctly.

So I've replaced `view.layoutIfNeeded()` by the `CALayer`'s counterpart `view.layer.layoutIfNeeded()`, which resulted in the `safeAreaInsets` to be set correctly right away, thus solving my problem.

**TL;DR**

Replace

```
view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

by

```
view.layer.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: Not working, not useful if you are animating a view transtion.

Answer (score 1):

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.safeAreaInsets return none zero
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try `self.view.safeAreaInsets` instead of `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets`
Safe area insets seems to not fill on iOS 11.x.x devices when requested via application keyWindow.

Answer (score 1):

View layout is never guaranteed until layoutSubviews or viewDidLayoutSubviews. Never rely on sizes before these lifecycle methods. You will get inconsistent results if you do.

Answer (score 1):

To calculate safe area safeAreaInsets, try to obtain it in viewWIllAppear(), as in didLoad() the view have not been formed.
You will have the correct inset in willAppear!

Answer (score 0):

In case you cannot subclass, you can use this `UIView` extension.

It gives you an API like this:

```
view.onSafeAreaInsetsDidChange = { [unowned self] in
   self.updateSomeLayout()
}
```

The extension adds an `onSafeAreaInsetsDidChange` property using object association. Then swizzles the `UIView.safeAreaInsetsDidChange()` method to call the closure (if any).

```
extension UIView {
    
    typealias Action = () -> Void
    
    var onSafeAreaInsetsDidChange: Action? {
        get {
            associatedObject(for: "onSafeAreaInsetsDidChange") as? Action
        }
        set {
            Self.swizzleSafeAreaInsetsDidChangeIfNeeded()
            set(associatedObject: newValue, for: "onSafeAreaInsetsDidChange")
        }
    }
    
    static var swizzled = false
    
    static func swizzleSafeAreaInsetsDidChangeIfNeeded() {
        guard swizzled == false else { return }
        swizzle(
            method: "safeAreaInsetsDidChange",
            originalSelector: #selector(originalSafeAreaInsetsDidChange),
            swizzledSelector: #selector(swizzledSafeAreaInsetsDidChange),
            for: Self.self
        )
        swizzled = true
    }
    
    @objc func originalSafeAreaInsetsDidChange() {
        // Original implementaion will be copied here.
    }
    
    @objc func swizzledSafeAreaInsetsDidChange() {
        originalSafeAreaInsetsDidChange()
        onSafeAreaInsetsDidChange?()
    }
}
```

It uses some helpers (see [`NSObject+Extensions.swift`](https://github.com/Geri-Borbas/iOS.Package.Withable/blob/main/Withable/NSObject%2BExtensions.swift) and [`NSObject+Swizzle.swift`](https://github.com/Geri-Borbas/iOS.Blog.Keyboard_Avoidance/blob/main/Keyboard_Avoidance/KeyboardLayoutGuide/Extensions/NSObject%2BSwizzle.swift)), but you don't really need it if you use sizzling and object association APIs directly.