# Getting the root safe area of a UIViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a `UIViewController` that is part of my `UITabBarController` and I have a function that hides the tab bar to bring up a view at the bottom very similar to the picture below.

Basically whenever I get the safe area after hiding the tabBar, it doesn't adjust to the tab bar being hidden. I want to get the actual safe area if there wasn't a tab bar there so it will look the same across devices.

Is it possible to get the the root safe area insets without tab bar/navigation?

[image]

Comment: it is hard to imaging what you are doing in the code
did you present the new view controller?

Comment: I should have been a little more clear there, it isn't a new view controller but a UIView in the view controller that pops up and hides the tab bar simultaneously

Answer (score 2):

You can present in tab bar which will present on top of it so no need to hide the tab bar.

```
tabBarController?.present(yourViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use `AutoLayout` and want to keep your custom tab bar at the bottom of the screen while taking into account the safe area on iPhone X for example, you can simply use `view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor` to pin your custom view to the bottom of the screen.

For example:

```
let myCustomTabBar = UIView()
// ...
view.addSubview(myCustomTabBar)
myCustomTabBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
myCustomTabBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
myCustomTabBar.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
myCustomTabBar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
myCustomTabBar.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
```

If you want to know the safe area insets for your window (without taking into account your tab bar or navigation bar) you can access the `UIWindow`'s `safeAreaInsets` property, or check out its `safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame`.

You can also override the `viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange` of your `UIViewController` and make the needed adjustments depending on what behaviour you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
guard let rootView = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow else { return 0 }

        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {

//            let topInset = rootView.safeAreaInsets.top

            let bottomInset = rootView.safeAreaInsets.bottom



        } else {

            return rootView.bounds.height

        }
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47831485/2815002