# Root view controller offset issue from Safe Area

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, rootviewcontroller

When root view controller appears, the view seems like conflicting with safe area

[image]

But when I change tab and come back again to this tab again, is seems like everything is ok

[image]

**Edit:**

```
class Switcher {

static func updateRootVC(){
    
    let status = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "Accesstoken")
    let userID = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "UserId")
    let userName = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "UserName")
    let userImage = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "UserImage")

    if let currentUser = userID {
        requestManager.instance.userID = currentUser as! Int
    }
    if let currentStatus = status {
        requestManager.instance.getToken = currentStatus as? String
    }
    if let Name = userName {
        Api.Params.inputUserName = (Name as? String)!
    }
    if let Image = userImage {
        Api.Params.inputUserImage = (Image as? String)!
    }
    
    
    var rootVC : UIViewController?

    if(status != nil){
        rootVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Tabbar", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Tabbar") as! UITabBarController
    } else {
        rootVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "welcome") as! UINavigationController
    }
    
    rootVC!.view.insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea = true


    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = rootVC
    appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    
}}
```

**Contraints of search items**

user profile has the same top as search items.

[image]

**TabViewController setup Code**

```
    func setupTabbar(){
    if Api.Params.isGuest == true {
        let vc1 = storyboardTabbar.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "home") as! UINavigationController
        let vc2 = storyboardTabbar.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "favorite") as! GuestVC
        let vc3 = storyboardTabbar.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "scanner") as! ScannerVC
        let vc4 = storyboardTabbar.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "history") as! GuestVC
        let vc5 = storyboardTabbar.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "settings") as! GuestVC
        self.viewControllers = [vc1 , vc2 , vc3 , vc4 , vc5]
        self.selectedViewController = vc1

    } else if Api.Params.isLanguageChange == true{
        Api.Params.isLanguageChange = !Api.Params.isLanguageChange
        let vc1 = storyboardTabbar.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "home") as! UINavigationController
        let vc2 = storyboardTabbar.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "fav") as! UINavigationController
        let vc3 = storyboardTabbar.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "scanner") as! ScannerVC
        let vc4 = storyboardTabbar.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "his") as! UINavigationController
        let vc5 = storyboardTabbar.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "set") as! UINavigationController
        self.viewControllers = [vc1 , vc2 , vc3 , vc4 , vc5]
        self.selectedViewController = vc5
    } else {
        let vc1 = storyboardTabbar.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "home") as! UINavigationController
        let vc2 = storyboardTabbar.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "fav") as! UINavigationController
        let vc3 = storyboardTabbar.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "scanner") as! ScannerVC
        let vc4 = storyboardTabbar.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "his") as! UINavigationController
        let vc5 = storyboardTabbar.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "set") as! UINavigationController
        self.viewControllers = [vc1 , vc2 , vc3 , vc4 , vc5]
        self.selectedViewController = vc1
    } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After so many days , finally found out that top constraint to safeArea cause the issue , changing that to Superview done the trick

[image]

Comment: Good, it's great

Comment: With this method you will get an unwanted margin on the top of the screen if the device doesn't have a notch. I had exactly the same problem and this was the solution that helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50418550/575882

As it turns out, in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method the safe area is not set yet (keyWindow.safeAreaInsets.top is 0). So if you create the TabBarController and all its subviews  here, the subview will be rendered on the whole screen.

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying the view insets layout from safeArea using the [insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/2891101-insetslayoutmarginsfromsafearea) property:

```
rootVC.view.insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea = true
```

Comment: Try before `let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate`

Answer (score 1):

When you're setting your constraints, use safeAreaLayoutGuide

Comment: its still not working :( , i have mark checked safeAreaLayoutGuide in storyboard

Answer (score 1):

You can try this in your Switcher class, I hope it helps you

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let navigationController: UINavigationController?
let storyboard: UIStoryboard?;

if status != nil {

    storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Tabs", bundle: nil)

    // HomeTabBarController is a subclass of UITabBarController
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeTabBarController") as! HomeTabBarController
    navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
} else {

    storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    // MainViewController is a subclass of UIViewController
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController") as! MainViewController
    navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)

}

// This hides the navigationBar
navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true

appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: You can share us the constraints you have of the elements that are in the upper part of the view, those that are above Category label

Comment: I do not see something strange in your layout constraints, you have tried in an emulator or Apple device that does not have Notch to verify that the same does not happen, example iPhone 7 or 8? The other thing I can recommend is to try to put a border to your elements, each one of a different color, so that you can visually identify which element is being stretched in size in execution and see if there is something with that element.

Comment: i think it might be because of the way i am setting in tabViewController , im adding Screenshot of TabViewController .. check the edit