# safeAreaInsets changes its value after keyboard dismissed in iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nsnotificationcenter, safearealayoutguide

I have bottomView (the one with black border in the images) its bottom anchor has a constraint to bottom view safeAreaLayoutGuide, but when keyboard will show the bottomView became toolbar to the keyboard.

Here every thing was working as expected in **iOS 14** (like image 1 and 3) but when running the project in **iOS 13** I found that safeAreaInsets changes its value after the keyboard dismissed (red space increases its height like image 2)

I've tried some of the solutions that mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47032855/safeareainsets-in-uiview-is-0-on-an-iphone-x) but it didn't help
can anyone suggest a solution for this?

```
 @objc func adjustForKeyboard(notification: Notification) {
        guard let keyboardValue = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else { return }

        let keyboardScreenEndFrame = keyboardValue.cgRectValue
        let keyboardViewEndFrame = view.convert(keyboardScreenEndFrame, from: view.window)
        if notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification {
            bottomViewConstraint?.constant = 0
            NotesText.contentInset = .zero
        
        } else {
            
            bottomViewConstraint?.constant = -(keyboardViewEndFrame.height - self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom)
            NotesText.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: -(keyboardViewEndFrame.height + bottomViewConstraint!.constant), right: 0)
            //FIXME:- force unwrap
        }

        NotesText.scrollIndicatorInsets = NotesText.contentInset

        let selectedRange = NotesText.selectedRange
        NotesText.scrollRangeToVisible(selectedRange)
        
        
    }
```

and called this function in viewDidAppear also tried to called it at viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange but the behavior didn't change

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        addKeyboardNotification()
        
        // Show keyboard by default
        NotesText.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
```

Keyboard notification function:

```
 fileprivate func addKeyboardNotification() {

        let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default

        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(adjustForKeyboard), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(adjustForKeyboard), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)

    }
```

[image: one]

[image: two]

[image: three]

Comment: it turns out that I forgot to make the anchor with -ve number