# How to consolidate button from top equally on iPhone X and other devices

Tags: ios, autolayout

I met this problem and can't solve it. 
I want that my cancel-button will consolidate from top screen on 20px, but on iPhone X screen it's more than 20.
[image: What I want photo].
Important: my button make moving with my scroll and to be from top 20px already.
My constraints: 
- Align top to: Safe Area; Trailling space to: Superview; Width equalls: 43.

Comment: Try changing the constraint  - `Align top to : Safe Area` to `Align top to : View` .

Comment: if I do like you say, that my button with scrolling stay on top (off-screen), but I want that my button moved with content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go with two approach which ever suits in your scenario :

1) Write code according to the device :

Add an `IBOutlet` for `Align top to : Safe Area` constraint of button and increase decrease the `yourHeightConstraintOutlet.constant` according to the device.

Below link will help you to write device specific code:

- [Detect if the device is iPhone X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46192280/detect-if-the-device-is-iphone-xuote)

2) You can change the `Align top to : Safe Area` constraint of `scrollView` to `Align top to : View`