# How to change the code according to the screen size of iPhone 8, X or iPad

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

I found a code in another article.

```
if([[UIDevice currentDevice]userInterfaceIdiom]==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
 {
     if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)
     {


     }
     else
     {
         //iphone 3.5 inch screen
     }
 }
 else
 {
        //[ipad]
 }
```

This article is the article code of 5 years ago.
I think that it is too old.
Because it is not compatible with iPhone 10.

Please tell me the latest code that allows for flexibility.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect if the device is iPhone X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46192280/detect-if-the-device-is-iphone-x)

Comment: @trungduc Thanks for comments. ad i found code 'if UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom =...'. I think this code is good for me. :)

Comment: @trungduc Thanks i did it !! This problem solved. please write as answer. then i check mark.

Comment: Actually it's not my answer so I think you should upvote the answer in above link instead. Don't forget to go around Google before creating a new question at the next time :)

Comment: @trungduc Okie :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use in my apps; it works a treat:

```
if UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height == 2436 {
   // Device is iPhone X 
}else if UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .pad && UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height == 1668 {
   // Device is iPad Pro 10.5' X 
}else{ 
   //Device is something else 
}
```

If you go to the [Apple Developer Documentation Archive](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/Displays/Displays.html), you can pick out the properties you'd like to use to detect a specific device. Perhaps a `switch` statement would be more appropriate if there will be multiple cases.