# iPhone X UIScreen returning height as it was iPhone 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone-x

Looking at this question [Detect if the device is iPhone X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46192280/detect-if-the-device-is-iphone-x), I did the same code as there but I'm getting 560 for height and 320 for the width after running the code in a physical iPhone X in `viewDidLoad`. I read that `UIScreen` takes the device's display size. Any idea what could be causing this?

I made this code just to quick check the output.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", screenSize.height]);
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", screenSize.width]);
    NSLog(@"iPhone X");

}
```

Output:

```
560.000000
320.000000 
iPhone X
```

Comment: You are not using a Launch Screen Storyboard and you haven't added iPhone X launch images.

Comment: BTW - there's no need to detect screen size or device. In most cases, such code is misguided and an indication that the app is being written incorrectly. Not to mention a giant pain every time Apple comes out with a new device with a new screen size.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks, you're right the app didn't have iPhone x launch images.

Comment: You should be using a single launch screen storyboard instead of all of those separate launch images.

Comment: @rmaddy I know the thing is this app is really old and I have to give maintenance
to it, it doesn't even use auto-layout, so yeah it's a pain.

Comment: ...and there are safer ways to see if it's an iPhone X, like check the safe area.

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup the Launch Screen File

[xcodeproj] -> [General] -> [App Icons and Launch Images]

[image]

Comment: Or, in this case, just add the missing launch image.