# What's the device code (platform string) for iPhone XS, iPhone XR and iPhone XS Max?

Tags: ios, iphone

Can anyone who have access to  iPhone XS, iPhone XR and iPhone XS Max. Let me know the Device Platform String?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52315956/how-to-programatically-detect-iphone-xs-or-iphone-x

Answer (score 4):

Here is a list of platform strings and corresponding model names:

> 1. iPhone11,2 = iPhone XS
> 2. iPhone11,4 = iPhone XS Max (Global)
> 3. iPhone11,6 = iPhone XS Max (China)
> 4. iPhone11,8 = iPhone XR

There are two variants of the iPhone XS Max as mentioned [here](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/IPhone_XS_Max).

Answer (score 1):

I found following across the developer references:

```
XR = iPhone11,8

XS = iPhone11,2

XS Max = iPhone11,4
```

Note: I will update these when actual devices are out.