# iOS: Detect if the device is iPhone X family (frameless)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, ios11

In my app there is some logic for frameless devices (iPhoneX, Xs Xs max, Xr). Currently it works base on the model of the devices, so, I detect the model by DeviceKit framework.

But I want to extend this logic to future frameless devices. Probably in one year we will have some extra frameless devices. So, how can I detect if device is frameless or not? It should cover all current frameless devices and future one.

We can not rely on faceID, safeAreaInset, screen height or size. So, then what?

Comment: Don't make decisions in you app based on the screen size. It's simply not scalable and hard to maintain.

Comment: @Cristik, yes, i know that

Comment: Apple doesn't make a lot of different models that run iOS so just update the list of devices as they come out. I'd imagine this would be about 10 minutes of work per year.

Comment: @slickdaddy, the app is for clients, and they do not want to push a lot of updates, i want to save their time

Comment: see this for e.g : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46192280/detect-if-the-device-is-iphone-x/46192822#46192822

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52821290/3472073

Comment: @Cristik what do you mean? Every mobile breakpoint style is a "decision in your app based on the screen size"

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You could "filter" for the top notch, something like:

```
var hasTopNotch: Bool {
    if #available(iOS 11.0, tvOS 11.0, *) {
        return UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.safeAreaInsets.top ?? 0 > 20
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work for iPad Pro where statusBarHeight is 24pt

Comment: MarekR -> try ".bottom instead of .top"

Comment: "fitler" ??? Did you mean "filter" ?

Comment: It doesn't work for landscape iPhone orientation, because in this case safe Area Insets.top is equal to 0.0, but safeAreaInsets.left or safeAreaInsets.right wouldn't be that's why they should be checked too.

Answer (score 26):

**Swift 5, iOS 14 supported**

Thanks to @Tanin and @DominicMDev, since `keyWindow was deprecated in iOS 13` and `the iPad Pro has non-zero safeAreaInsets`, this works fine for me.

(Already tested on `iPhone 8`, `iPhone 11 Pro` and `iPad Pro (11-inch)(2nd gen)` Simulators)

```swift
extension UIDevice {
    /// Returns `true` if the device has a notch
    var hasNotch: Bool {
        guard #available(iOS 11.0, *), let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter({$0.isKeyWindow}).first else { return false }
        if UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait {
            return window.safeAreaInsets.top >= 44
        } else {
            return window.safeAreaInsets.left > 0 || window.safeAreaInsets.right > 0
        }
    }
}
```

Example of usage:

```
print(UIDevice.current.hasNotch)
```

Comment: @NikhilMuskur I've tried on iPhone 8 Plus, iPhone 12 Pro and iPad Pro (11-inch) on iOS 14.1, Xcode 12.1 just now and it works well. What's your condition?

Comment: Everything works correctly in the simulator but when I run this on a device the `isPortrait` property is always false

Comment: @NikhilMuskur can you give a more precise description about your situation? On what device and how do you specified the `isPortrait` property is always false?

Comment: While debugging I found that `UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait` always returned false and `window.safeAreaInsets.left` was equal to 0. I tested this on iPhone 11. Strangely the condition is working correctly on the simulator

Comment: @NikhilMuskur Well I've tested on my iPhone X and `UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait` works well ( return true when portrait )...

Comment: Can confirm, not working, for the rootViewController of UIVindow, later on - it works

Comment: This will also be `true` if the phone has the dynamic island.

Answer (score 11):

Since `keyWindow was deprecated in iOS 13`, based on the solution to find `keyWindow` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57134259/how-to-resolve-keywindow-was-deprecated-in-ios-13-0), this one works for me

```
extension UIDevice {
    var hasNotch: Bool {
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first
            return keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets.bottom ?? 0 > 0
        }
        return false
    }

}
```

Comment: This breaks on iPad 11 inch 3 generation, because that device has a `keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets.bottom == 20` because it does not have a bottom button. The answer from "Saafo" is what I used in the end.

Answer (score 7):

This is valid for any orientation. 
No need to worry about iOS version before 11.0 since iPhone X minimum version is 11.0. [Source](http://%20https://medium.com/@cafielo/how-to-detect-notch-screen-in-swift-56271827625d)

```
extension UIDevice {

    var hasNotch: Bool {
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
           return UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets.bottom ?? 0 > 0
        }
        return false
   }
}
```

Comment: keyWindow is now deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

```
extension UIDevice {
    var hasNotch: Bool
    {
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *)
        {
            let bottom = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets.bottom ?? 0
            return bottom > 0
        } else
        {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Using by

```
if UIDevice.current.hasNotch 
{
    //... consider notch
} 
else 
{
   //... don't have to consider notch
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 5**

```
var hasNotch: Bool {
    if #available(iOS 11.0, tvOS 11.0, *) {
        let bottom = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets.bottom ?? 0
        return bottom > 0
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am doing it like this because the iPadPro has non-zero safeAreaInsets.

```
extension UIDevice {

    /// Returns 'true' if the device has a notch
    var hasNotch: Bool {
        guard #available(iOS 11.0, *), let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow else { return false }
        let orientation = UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation
        if orientation.isPortrait {
            return window.safeAreaInsets.top >= 44
        } else {
            return window.safeAreaInsets.left > 0 || window.safeAreaInsets.right > 0
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since ⚠️Device Orientation != Interface Orientation⚠️

My final code is:

```
extension UIDevice {
    var hasNotch: Bool {
        guard #available(iOS 11.0, *), let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter({$0.isKeyWindow}).first else { return false }
        //if UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait {  //Device Orientation != Interface Orientation
        if let o = windowInterfaceOrientation?.isPortrait, o == true {
            return window.safeAreaInsets.top >= 44
        } else {
            return window.safeAreaInsets.left > 0 || window.safeAreaInsets.right > 0
        }
    }
    
    private var windowInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation? {
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            return UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.windowScene?.interfaceOrientation
        } else {
            return UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For SwiftUI using scene delegate:

```
  var hasNotch: Bool {
    guard let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first,
          let windowSceneDelegate = scene.delegate as? UIWindowSceneDelegate,
          let window = windowSceneDelegate.window else {
      return false
    }

    return window?.safeAreaInsets.top ?? 0 > 20
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on all the answers offered, I needed another way. I created an enumeration with all the necessary interface nuances and return the required type in a variable:

```
enum DeviceInterfaceType {
    case dynamicIsland
    case notch
    case none
}

extension UIDevice {

    var interfaceType: DeviceInterfaceType {
        guard let window = (UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.compactMap { $0 as? UIWindowScene }.flatMap { $0.windows }.first { $0.isKeyWindow}) else {
        return .none
        }

        if window.safeAreaInsets.top >= 51 && userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
            return .dynamicIsland
        } else if window.safeAreaInsets.top >= 44 {
            return .notch
        } else if window.safeAreaInsets.left > 0 || window.safeAreaInsets.right > 0 {
            return .none
        }

        return .none
    }

}
```

Function call

```
switch UIDevice.current.interfaceType {
case .dynamicIsland:
//
case .notch:
//
case .none:
//
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This way you can cover all the orientations:

```
var hasTopNotch: Bool 
{
    if #available(iOS 11.0,  *) {

        var safeAreaInset: CGFloat?
        if (UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation == .portrait) {
            safeAreaInset = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.safeAreaInsets.top
        }
        else if (UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation == .landscapeLeft) {
            safeAreaInset = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.safeAreaInsets.left
        }
        else if (UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation == .landscapeRight) {
            safeAreaInset = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.safeAreaInsets.right
        }
        return safeAreaInset ?? 0 > 24
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
safeTop = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.safeAreaInsets.top ?? 0

if safeTop > 20 { 
   print("Big family")
} else {
   print("Before X")
}
```

**Swift 5.0**
The most simple to understand and adapt to your conditions.

Comment: This didn't work for me — printed "Before X" when using iPhone 14.

Answer (score 0):

```
var hasNotch: Bool {
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            if UIApplication.shared.windows.count == 0 { return false }          // Should never occur, but…
            let top = UIApplication.shared.windows[0].safeAreaInsets.top
            return top > 20          // That seem to be the minimum top when no notch…
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            return false
        }
    }
```

Comment: refs: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/127113?page=2

Answer (score 0):

```
func isIphoneX() -> Bool {
    guard #available(iOS 11.0, *),
      let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter({$0.isKeyWindow}).first else { return false }

    return window.safeAreaInsets.top >= 44
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the notch in your UIViewController just set up isNotch flag in the method viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange()

```
open override func viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange() {
    super.viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange()
    isNotch = true
}
```

I've tested it on Simulator only. It is called only in X devices in all orientations.

Answer (score 0):

when you have

> sceneDelegate.swift

class. This Will Work

```
 extension UIDevice {
        var hasNotch: Bool {
            if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                if UIApplication.shared.windows.count == 0 { return false }          // Should never occur, but…
                let top = UIApplication.shared.windows[0].safeAreaInsets.top
                return top > 20          // That seems to be the minimum top when no notch…
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
                return false
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've built upon Saafo's answer as `UIApplication.shared.windows` is now deprecated in iOS 15.0 and I've also defaulted to checking the top insert if the orientation is unknown

[image: xcode warning on deprecated function]

```swift
extension UIDevice {

    var hasNotch: Bool {
        
        guard let firstScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene else {
            return false
        }

        guard let firstWindow = firstScene.windows.filter({$0.isKeyWindow}).first else {
            return false
        }
        
        if UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait ||
            UIDevice.current.orientation == .unknown {
            return firstWindow.safeAreaInsets.top >= 44
        } else {
            return firstWindow.safeAreaInsets.left > 0 || firstWindow.safeAreaInsets.right > 0
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
extension UIDevice {
    var hasNotch: Bool {
        let bottom = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets.bottom ?? 0
        return bottom > 0
    }
}
```

use 'UIDevice.current.hasNotch' will return true or false

Swift 5

```
var hasNotch: Bool {
    let bottom = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.safeAreaInsets.bottom ?? 0
    return bottom > 0
}
```

Comment: it is a good practice to advocate your code, consider adding some description to your answer

Comment: Also describe how your answer differs from the 8 existing answers.