# UITableViewCell ContentView size problem for plus size iPhones

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios12

I have UITableViewCell with Xib file. Everything looked fine until i tried my cell with plus size iPhones such as iPhone 7 Plus, 8 Plus and XS Max.

Cell height is 476px and it's contentView height is 475,5 as usual. However, when i tried plus sizes cells contentView height is 475,67px. What da heck is wrong with Interface Builder?

> iPhone SE, 7, 8, X, XR

[image: iPhone SE, 7, 8, X, XR]

> iPhone 7 Plus, 8 Plus, XS Max

[image: iPhone 7 Plus, 8 Plus, XS Max]

Answer (score 0):

If this tiny margin is causing such a big trouble then there are a couple workarounds you could do to fix it.

** Both workarounds will require code checking for plus sizes iPhones. Check here.
[Detect if the device is iPhone X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46192280/detect-if-the-device-is-iphone-x)

1. Create a separate cell to use it with plus sizes iPhones and set it's height to whatever is adueqate.
2. Or manage (heightForRowAtIndexPath) to return the desired height for plus sizes iPhones.