# Make UIView move down if iPhone is iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, iphone-5

I am currently creating an app which contains a pickerView and a tapbar within a view. The view is placed on the bottom of the screen. The tapbar is always visible. If I tap a button on the tapbar, the view will move up and show the pickerView.
My Problem is:

The view does not move down to the bottom of the iPhone 5 screen. I placed this code in different locations:

```
CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
if (screenSize.height > 480.0f){
    [UIView beginAnimations:Nil context:Nil];//tells the compiler to start a new animation
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.6];//in seconds
    self.hiddenView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 504, 320, 260);//move the picker to a specific position (504 = 568 - statusbar(20) - tapbar(44))
    [UIView commitAnimations];//tells the compiler to start the animations
}
```

such as in the:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{}
-(void)viedWillAppear{}
-(void)viewDidAppear{}
```

I am clueless. Does anyone know how to make it the right way?

**UPADTE**

Ok thanks for all the answers, but my animation works fine. My problem is that it is executed every time (checked using breakpoints) won't fire (the view won't move down). So I asked **WHERE** I have to put my code in order to work properly. Not if the code was correct, because it is. I know there are different ways to check if it is an iPhone 5 and to animate things, but again: this code is working and not the actual problem. I hope you understand my problem better now.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have time to write any example code but, rather than hard-coding specific numbers (480.0f or a frame size), Apple recommend you use the Auto-Layout / Constraints system which will also implicitly animate your changes.  Of course, this is only useful if you are targeting iOS 5+.

Comment: Ok this I think would do it, but I don't get how to make the right constraints. I tried a few things via the interface builder but it confused me more then it helped.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17288202/different-label-size-in-different-ios-device/17292509#17292509

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok since apparently nobody correctly understood my question (or didn't actually read it to the end?), I had to find an answer for myself. If somebody encounters the same problem here is how I solved it.

Just place your code into the `-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{}` function. It will execute as soon as the view is fully loaded.

```
   -(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
        CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
        if (screenSize.height > 480.0f){
            [UIView beginAnimations:Nil context:Nil];//tells the compiler to start a new animation
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.0];//in seconds
            self.hiddenView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 504, 320, 260);//move the picker to a specific position
            [UIView commitAnimations];//tells the compiler to start the animations
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to figure out why my view wouldn't move - was going crazy.

Answer (score 1):

Use this below code.

```
if([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)
{
    //This is for iphone 5 view
    //add your code here.
    UIView *view=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 150, 100, 100)];

}
else
{
    //This is for iphone 4 view
    //add your code here.
    UIView *view=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
}
```

This condition for iphone 5 .

Comment: Allocating a new view didn't work. It just moves back to the iPhone 4 position, instead of moving to the new CGRectMake position.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to `comparision` of height for different `ios`:
Try this for hide your view:

```
CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
[UIView beginAnimations:Nil context:Nil];//tells the compiler to start a new animation
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.6];//in seconds
self.hiddenView.frame = CGRectMake(0, screenSize.height, 320, 260);//move the picker to a specific position
[UIView commitAnimations];//tells the compiler to start the animations
```

To show your view:

```
CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    [UIView beginAnimations:Nil context:Nil];//tells the compiler to start a new animation
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.6];//in seconds
    self.hiddenView.frame = CGRectMake(0, screenSize.height-260, 320, 260);//move the picker to a specific position
    [UIView commitAnimations];//tells the compiler to start the animations
```

> **Update**
>   you can take a `bool` variable or can use selected state of your `tapButton`
>   Like:

```
-(IBAction) tapbuttonClicked:(UIButton *)sender
{
     [sender setSelected:!sender.isSelected];
     if(sender.isSelected)
      {
        //code to show your view...
      }
      else
      {
        //code to hide....
       }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but it actually was not my problem. Look at the Update please.

Answer (score 0):

Add The following line of code:

```
#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )
```

At `yourProjectName-perfix.pch` file

This is useful for recognize that device is iPhone4 or iPhone5. by give condition  such like

```
if (IS_IPHONE_5)
{
    //// write code/setFrame for iPhone5;
}
eles
{
    //// write code/setFrame for iPhone4;
}
```

Use it anyWhere in your project:

Comment: Thanks for that, but it actually was not my problem. Look at the Update please.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite way of doing such things is using `+ (UIView) animateWithDuration: animations:`

```
CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
if (screenSize.height > 480.0f){
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.60f animations:^(void){
self.hiddenView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 504, 320, 260);//move the picker to a specific position (504 = 568 - statusbar(20) - tapbar(44))
}];
}
```

This should do the trick for you. Also, you can look at `animateWithDuration: animations: completion:` or even `animateWithDuration: delay: options: animations: completion:`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didn't help me. I thought maybe the delay element would do it, but it didn't. The view just moved to the iPhone 4 position a second later. It doesn't matter what CGRechtMake I define, it will always move to the iPhone 4 position.