# Resizing a UIImageView programmatically

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I have tried several different solutions to this problem with no success.

I have a `UIImageView` (created on the Storyboard) that has multiple Gesture Recognizers on it. I have trying to resize this `UIImageView` based on screen size to take advantage of the 4 inch display.

It appears that since the Imageview was built using the storyboard, I can't change it programmatically???

My current code looks like this:

```
//determine screen size, set scoring button width based on device size.
CGFloat lCurrentHeight = self.view.bounds.size.height;
if (lCurrentHeight == 568.0) {
    CGRect _redHeadImageFrame = _redHeadImage.frame;
    _redHeadImageFrame.size.width = 220;
    [_redHeadImage setFrame:_redHeadImageFrame];
}
```

Any ideas??? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you need to use like this,

```
CGFloat lCurrentHeight = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height; //it will give 568

CGFloat lCurrentHeight = self.view.bounds.size.height;//it will give 548,in your case that condition failed.
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using autolayout you have to change withConstraint of the image, because manual changing of the frame will not work in this case.

**EDIT**

You can create IBOutlet for the width constraint as you do it for other controls - just select constraint in IB and move it with right button to your header file. Than in code change constraint:

```
[self.imageWidthConstraint setConstant:100.0];
```

Comment: I am using auto layout.  In IB there are two constraints on this image width, and align trailing edge (which is want I want to have change with the new frame).  How do I use withConstraints when setting the new frame? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference in resizing `UIViews` created by code or by the storyboard. It's exactly the same: setting the frame of the view, as you are doing.

What might be happening:

1. Your if condition it's never true. Have you checked with a breakpoint if the code inside it is even called? Maybe there's some error in the float direct comparation. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334688/how-dangerous-is-it-to-compare-floating-point-values).
   Also, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446990/how-to-detect-iphone-5-widescreen-devices) for a better understanding on how to check if it's 4 inch display.
2. If the `setFrame:` code is actually called, check if you are using auto-layout in your view. Maybe there's a constraint in the `UIImageView`. In this case, you should play with this constraint, in order to resize the view correctly..