# Why my whole image is not displayed while running app in iphone (Retina 4 inch)

Tags: iphone, background-image, retina-display, iphone-5

I set background of view as below:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:
@"backgr.png"]];
```

It is working fine when i run it in **iphone 4(Retina 3.5-inch).** But when i run it in **iphone 5(Retina 4-inch)** image didn't set or displayed correctly.Image looks like 4 times zoom in/
blows up.

**EDIT**:

```
 I have two different images for iphone 4(640x960) and 5(640x1136).

 What is the problem here? Is it scaling problem or another problem?
 Please guide me on this.
```

Answer (score 1):

the resolution for both the displays are different so you need to put condition and accordingly set the new image with higher resolution for iPhone 5 (4 inch retina) display.

and that condition you can put like

```
if ((int)[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)
{
    // This is iPhone 5 screen
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backgr_iPhone5.png"]];
} else {
    // This is iPhone 4 screen
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backgr.png"]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that can be handy :

```
#define IS_PHONEPOD5() ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568.0f && 
[UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2.f &&
 UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
```

and

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

        if(IS_PHONEPOD5())
        {
                self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image-568h@2x"];
        }
        else
        {
                self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image"];
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use two different image for iPhone 4 and iPhone 5.Because both device have different resolution. You need to check like this.

```
if ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568)
    {
        // ------- iPhone 5
    }
    else
    {
        // ---------- iPhone 4
    }
```

Comment: iPhone 5 screen height is 568 friend.

Comment: Please see my updated question.I am already using two different images for iphone 4 and 5.

Comment: Ponting, Have you @2x image in your project ?

Comment: @DharmbirChoudhary : better you watch this question and answer this way you'll came to know weather i am an iphone developer or you are http://stackoverflow.com/q/12446990/2695503

Comment: @eptdeveloper i Know dear but i'm checking greater or equal to 548. So i think it should not be wrong. But if u wanna then i can do. But accoding to me its not wrong..

Comment: What you test in your if(...) statement is not thorough, please have a look at my answer.