# How to set screen compatible to both 3.5 and 4 inch display in iPhone application

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

i developed iphone application and finished everything that fits on 3.5 inch display. i also need the same thing to be fit on 4 inch display. I set the splash screen and home screen and its display fits on both the devices. 
Then tried Use auto layout for other pages. its not working. Could you please tell me how to set the other screens.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do some research before posting a question. This has been asked over and over before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put following macro in `yourAppName-Prefix.pch`

```
#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )
```

So you can use anywhere in your project.

And put condition such like

```
if (IS_IPHONE_5)
{
     //iPhone  4 inch
}
else
{

     //iPhone  3.5 inch
}
```

Also for more [information read this question/answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446990/how-to-detect-iphone-5-widescreen-devices)

Comment: I am new to this topic. So please tell me in which file i have to paste the if condition.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the dynamic frame instead of Hard-coded frame,

You can use `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];` to determine the device height and width.

For example:

```
CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

UIView * myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];

[self.view addSubview:myView];

myView = nil;
```

Thanks!

Comment: i am new to this topic. So please tell me in which file i have to write this codes.