# Is there a way to tell what model iOS device is connected using Game Center?

Tags: ios, game-center, gamekit

Programmed in Objective C, my application is able to use GameKit to connect two iPhone 5(S) Devices and pass data between them. Problems, however, have started to occur now that I'm porting the game to work on devices of a different screen sizes (most notably, the 3.5 inch iPhone 4S). While/After creating a real-time match between the devices, is there a way to detect the **Opposing Device's Screen Size**. If not, is there a way to detect the opposing device's model. 
All help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not exchange that info from one device to other.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a piece of code into your application that detects the screen size:

```
[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height
```

Each group of devices has a different height (4 vs. 5). You can make it so that only devices with a certain height match with a device of the same height (different methods to do the same task).

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446990/how-to-detect-iphone-5-widescreen-devices) for more information on determining between different devices.