# Xcode - Declaring separate story boards for separate game features

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

so in my app im using the storyboard for most of the game. I originally created the game and story board based off of the iphone 5+ (4 in) screen. I wanted to have it also compatiable with the iphone 4 (3.5 in) screen. So in app delegate i made it load 2 different story boards depending on the height.

Anyways, but now in the game there are parts of the game that was specifically coordinate placed objects that still get cut off on the bottom on the 3.5 in sceen. So what i need help with is some way to declare its running the 4 inch story  board or the 3.5 inch storyboard

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need 2 separate story boards? Using the auto-layout function in Interface Builder is recommended, have you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12447113/2443525) thread?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need separate storyboard just to handle 3.5" and 4 " device. Autolayout or Autoresizing (if you arn't interested in text resizing and iphone 6 may be) can get the job done.

If you stll want to go ahead making separate storyboard , have a look at https://github.com/rob-brown/RBStoryboardLink