# App Store Connect Screenshots Sizes for all iOS (iPhone/iPad/Apple Watch) devices

Tags: iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

I'm trying to submit a new application to the App Store but now Apple requires screenshots for iPhones of 4.7 inch and 5.5 inch. Anyone has these screenshot specifications (size)?

I tried with:

- 640 x 1136 (portrait)
- 640 x 1096 (portrait)
- 1136 x 640 (landscape)
- 1136 x 600 (landscape)

I also tried to use iPad's size screenshots, but that didn't work either. I didn't receive any advice or email from Apple with this information and I don't see any help in iTunes Connect.

Comment: Has Apple a web page that describes the new screen shot requirements? This [page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html) hasn't been updated yet.

Comment: I made a search, but I can't find anything about the new resolutions sizes. Also, I'm looking in the Development Resources. Still no luck.

Comment: it's updated https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html

Comment: Updated 2017 link : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW2

Comment: 2019: https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devd274dd925

Answer (score 551, accepted):

The following resolutions are acceptable to iTunes connect:

| Inch | Height*Width | Devices |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3.5 | 640 x 960 | iPhone 3+4 |
| 4 | 640 x 1136 | iPhone 5, iPhone 5S, iPhone 5C |
| 4.7 | 750 x 1334 | iPhone 6, iPhone 6S, iPhone 7, iPhone 8 |
| 5.5 | 1242 x 2208 | iPhone 6 Plus, iPhone 6S Plus, iPhone 7 Plus, iPhone 8 Plus |
| 5.8 | 1125 x 2436 | iPhone X, iPhone XS |
| 6.1 | 828 x 1792 | iPhone XR |
| 6.5 | 1242 x 2688 | iPhone 13 Pro Max, iPhone 12 Pro Max, iPhone 11 Pro Max, iPhone XS Max, iPhone XR |
| 6.7 | 1290 x 2796 | iPhone 14 Pro Max |
| 7.9 | 1536 x 2048 | iPad Mini 2, iPad Mini 3, iPad Mini 4 |
| 9.7 | 1536 x 2048 | iPad 3, iPad 4, iPad Pro, iPad Air, iPad Air 2 |
| 10.5 | 1668 x 2224 | iPad Pro |
| 12.9 | 2048 x 2732 | iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th generation) |
| 1.5 | 272 x 340 | Apple Watch Series 1, Apple Watch Series 2, Apple Watch Series 3 - 38mm |
| 1.57 | 394 x 324 | Apple Watch Series 4 - 40mm |
| 1.65 | 312 x 390 | Apple Watch Series 1, Apple Watch Series 2, Apple Watch Series 3 - 42mm |
| 1.78 | 448 x 368 | Apple Watch Series 4 - 44mm |

Even [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW2) on the matter is incomplete.

Update: Apple has [introduced a new Media Manager](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=08082016a) which requires only that you create artwork for the largest iPhone and/or iPad devices. The smaller images will be created for you. Note that if you hadn't been creating iPad Pro images before, you have to now (if you support iPad).

Update: [Screenshots and app previews for new devices now supported](https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/news/100002380).

Comment: Could you explain how you get to 'iPhone 6 Plus ( 2208 x 1242 )'? Because apple phone specs give you 1920x1080 pixel size for plus...

Comment: @queenie, 3x. The 5.5-inch screenshots are 2208 x 1242, not 1920 x 1080.

Comment: @northtree So is Apple advertising the wrong size then? http://www.apple.com/iphone-6/display/ says the screen is 1920x1080

Comment: @Ben Clayton I have uploaded the screenshots in ITC today. Only the size of 2208 x 1242 is OK.

Comment: @Orgmir Maybe for the landscape orientation? Or for the higher than higher PPI?

Comment: I noticed the different dimensions as well by taking a screenshot of the iPhone 6 Plus simulator.

Comment: These sizes works for me:
iPhone 6: 750 × 1334 or 1334 x 750
iPhone 6 Plus: 1242 × 2208 or 2208 x 1242

Comment: @BenClayton The image on iPhone 6 Plus is downsampled by 1.15 into lower pixel resolution. http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/iphone-6-screens-demystified. I guess the iPhone 7 maybe 2208 x 1242 pixels.

Comment: what will happen if we don't provide iphone6 screenshots, will the app disappear from app store on iphone6 devices?

Comment: I get the error "the dimensions of one or more screenshots are wrong"

Comment: If you use the either the Xcode "take screen shot" (from the Devices menu) or the Simulator File-> Save screen shot, you get the correct 2208 x 1242 resolution for uploading to iTunes connect.  In my guess, "woof", I couldn't upload to the store without the correct screenshots.

Comment: scaling **IS** indeed changing the screenshot resolution.

Comment: When Apple rolled out their new "Media Manager" they gave us a new benefit of only having to upload the largest of the device screenshot sizes. However, they now **require you to create iPad Pro** size screenshots if you support iPad. This is disappointing if you discover this after receiving the normal assets for 80+ apps you are updating and have to go back to your UX team for new iPad Pro art they have never had to create. #sigh

Comment: Nice Description Screen wise.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/Properties.html

Comment: What about landscape screenshots?

Comment: Added iPhone X screenshots dimensions: https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/news/5993372

Comment: The simulator adds rounded corners and sensor housing place in the screenshots. Should they be uploaded as it is?

Comment: Thank you for valuable informations, please can you tell me If i only add app preview video for 5.5 inch model, won't iPhone X, Xs, Xr models see this app preview video in app store?

Answer (score 336):

*This answer is updated for Xcode 14.*

App Store Connect currently asks for images in the following categories:

[image]

### iPhone 6.7" Display

This is `1290 x 2796` pixels. You can use the following simulators to create these screenshots:

- iPhone 14 Pro Max

### iPhone 6.5" Display

*As long as you have iPhone 6.7" screenshots, App Store Connect allows you to omit this one.*

This is `1242 x 2688` pixels. You can use the following simulators to create these screenshots:

- iPhone 13 Pro Max
- iPhone 12 Pro Max
- iPhone 11 Pro Max
- iPhone XS Max
- iPhone XR

### iPhone 5.5" Display

This is `1242 x 2208` pixels. You can use the following simulators to create these screenshots:

- iPhone 8 Plus
- iPhone 7 Plus
- iPhone 6s Plus

*Xcode 14 doesn't show these devices by default in the Simulator. In Xcode, go to Window > Devices and Simulators. Chose Simulators and then press the add button to add iPhone 8 Plus to the list.*

### iPad Pro (6th gen) 12.9" Display

That is `2048 x 2732` pixels. You can create this size image using the **iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (6th generation)** simulator.

### iPad Pro (2nd gen) 12.9" Display

That is `2048 x 2732` pixels. This is the exact same size as the **iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (6th generation)**, so most people can use the same screenshots here. But see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54271920/why-is-there-an-option-for-two-12-9-size-screenshots-in-app-store-connect).

### Notes

- Data source: Official [Screenshot specifications](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devd274dd925) page on the Apple site. Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62241682) for the link. Not all of the devices listed above produce the exact pixel dimensions listed, but Apple seems to accept the proportions.
- Use **File > New Screen Shot** (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) in the simulator to save a screenshot to the desktop. On a real device press <kbd>Sleep/Wake</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> [on the iPhone/iPad](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT200289) (images available in Photo app)
- The pixel dimensions above are the full screen portrait orientation sizes. You shouldn't include the status bar, so you can either paste background color over the status bar text and icons or crop them out and scale the image back up.

Comment: For those of us still wondering, these are still accurate today!!!

Comment: @Omega_Pixel, whenever I update an app I usually come back here and make sure these pixel dimentions are up to date as well. If anyone finds that this answer is out of date in the future, feel free to edit it.

Comment: iPhone 11 didn't work for me for iPhone 6.5" Display. Used iPhone 13 Pro Max and it worked.

Comment: @BartekPacia, Good to know. Thanks. I removed it from the list.

Comment: Since mostly, you don't share just device screenshot but make it with an introduction text, I prefer to make a single case(with 14 pro max in this case) and relayout for 5.5, and making the 6.7 size smaller for 6.5 .

Answer (score 112):

To get screenshots of the proper size without having to create them manually --  run your app in the latest version of Xcode and choose the iPhone you need screenshots for, then hit cmd-s while viewing the simulator. This will save a screenshot to your desktop in the full resolution that you need for submission.

As noted below by @HoffZ, be sure that the scale is set to 100%.

In Xcode select simulator you want:

[image: Xcode simulators]

In the Simulator menu set the scale to 100%:

[image: Set Scale to 100%]

Press cmd-s to save:

[image: Save Screenshot]

Comment: Two things to note: 1) The image is saved to the Desktop. 2) Make sure that the scale is 100% (Window->Scale in simulator).

Comment: This is a great answer and I hope to try it later from my Mac, because so far I've attempted to upload various image sizes that match the docs at : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/writerid/itc_screenshot_properties
All of my images fail even though they match the specs it says they are the wrong dimensions.  Really confusing.  Thanks for the hint how to get there.

Comment: I don't think it is required the that scale is set to 100%. The iPad Pro 12 inch simulator will not come close to fitting on my MacBook's display at 100%, yet screenshots are still saved at full resolution.

Comment: This is the best answer really cause unlike the others it's timeless!!

Comment: Confirming 100 % scale isn't needed. Screenshot is always in full resolution.

Comment: and dont forget to use safari browser when you upload the image to iTunesConnect ,  it does not work with chrome

Answer (score 19):

In Xcode 9, in addition to setting the Window Scale to 100% (⌘1) it is now necessary to also uncheck `Optimize Rendering for Window Scale` in the debug menu in order to get a screenshot of the proper resolution.

To take a screenshot of the proper size for use on the app store:

1.) Run app in simulator
2.) Set scale (⌘1)
3.) Uncheck `Optimize Rendering for Window Scale`in debug menu
4.) Take a Screenshot with ⌘S

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much! :)

Answer (score 8):

[Apple Link](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devd274dd925)

Below is the information about screen sizes. These details are taken from the apple website

[image: Below is the information]

Answer (score 7):

(Cross-posting my answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25775147/798533)

For anybody looking for the resolution of the image to upload (if you want to create some fancy photoshop screenshots), they are:

- iPhone 6: 750 × 1334
- iPhone 6 Plus: 1242 × 2208

Good reference guide here: http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/iphone-6-screens-demystified (talks about resolutions and downsampling of the iPhone 6+).

Answer (score 6):

Now Apple Inc. added a new device screen shots also over iTunesconnect that is iPad Pro. Here are all sizes of screen shots which iTunesconnects requires.

- iPhone 6 Plus (5.5 inches) - 2208x1242
- iPhone 6 (4.7 inches) - 1334x750
- iPhone 5/5s (4 inches) - 1136x640
- iPhone 4s (3.5 inches) - 960x640
- iPad - 1024x768
- iPadPro - 2732x2048

Answer (score 5):

I know there are bunch of very well crafted answers. I found a correct documentation from apple website where they have specified the specification for screenshot requirements. Here is the link below
https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devd274dd925
[image: App Previews Screenshot Specs]

Answer (score 4):

Also - please note that you may have transparency set even if you don't actually have any transparency in your images.  If you're using photoshop, 'save for web' and de-select 'transparency' or just convert your image to a .jpg. iTunes Connect seems to reject transparencies as well.

Answer (score 4):

This is updated as of 6-14-2017 from the following source:
http://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/devd274dd925

**Screenshot specifications**

- 5.5-Inch Retina Display
  1242 x 2208 pixels for portrait
  2208 x 1242 pixels for landscape
- 4.7-Inch Retina Display
  750 x 1334 pixels for portrait
  1334 x 750 pixels for landscape
- 4-Inch Retina Display
  640 x 1096 pixels for portrait (without status bar)
  640 x 1136 pixels for portrait (full screen)
  1136 x 600 pixels for landscape (without status bar)
  1136 x 640 pixels for landscape (full screen)
- 3.5-Inch Retina Display
  640 x 920 pixels for portrait (without status bar)
  640 x 960 pixels for portrait (full screen)
  960 x 600 pixels for landscape (without status bar)
  960 x 640 pixels for landscape (full screen)
- 12.9-Inch Retina Display
  2048 x 2732 pixels for portrait
  2732 x 2048 pixels for landscape
- 9.7-Inch Retina Display
  High Resolution:
  2048 x 1496 pixels for landscape (without status bar)
  2048 x 1536 pixels for landscape (full screen)
  1536 x 2008 pixels for portrait (without status bar)
  1536 x 2048 pixels for portrait (full screen)
  Standard resolution:
  1024 x 748 pixels for landscape (without status bar)
  1024 x 768 pixels for landscape (full screen)
  768 x 1004 pixels for portrait (without status bar)
  768 x 1024 pixels for portrait (full screen)
- macOS
  One of the following, with a 16:10 aspect ratio.
  1280 x 800 pixels
  1440 x 900 pixels
  2560 x 1600 pixels
  2880 x 1800 pixels
- tvOS
  1920 x 1080 pixels
- watchOS
  312 x 390 pixels

Answer (score 2):

For iPhone 5.5" display you need to change the simulator to "Physical Size" on iPhone 8 Plus

[image: Physical size]

Answer (score 1):

For iPhone Devices : Now we need only one size
iPhone 6 Plus (5.5 Inch)
    •   1242 x 2208
Then we have check box there, in all other sizes to : Use 5.5-Inch Display

Comment: nice answer. Thank u Miss Aanchal.

Answer (score 1):

```
 1)iPhone X screenshot support in iTunes Connect.October 27, 2017.

 2)You can now upload screenshots for iPhone X. 
  You’ll see a new tab for 5.8-inch displays under Screenshots and App Previews on your iOS app  version information page.

 3)Note that iPhone X screenshots are optional and cannot be used for smaller devices sizes. 
  5.5-inchdisplay screenshots are still required for all apps that run on iPhone.

 4)iPhone X Screenshot Resolutions
  1125 by 2436 (Portrait)
  2436 by 1125 (Landscape)
```

Answer (score 1):

Via the simulators for respective devices, we can have screenshots with cmd+S command conveniently. And that gives us the exact resolution for the device we simulate. The review team would have mentioned this, but never did. :)

Answer (score 1):

for xcode 11.1which doesn't contain ipad pro 
iPad Pro (2nd Gen) 12.9" Display run this command in terminal

xcrun simctl create "iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (2nd generation)" "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Pro--12-9-inch---2nd-generation-" "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-1"

[look here](https://discuss.bitrise.io/t/xcode-11-missing-ipad-pro-12-9-inch-2nd-generation-on-ios-13/10431)

Answer (score 1):

I have this page bookmarked and refer back to it frequently, but no one mentions the size for newer 11 inch iPad pro. It's 1668x2388.

Here's a bash script that will resize generic screenshots to the appropriate dimensions. I could not get an iPhone 4 simulator running in the latest xcode as of 2020, so this was necessary for me.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

HERE="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )"

declare -A sizes
sizes["6-5-inch-iphone-xs-max"]="1242x2688"
sizes["5-8-inch-iphone-x"]="1125x2436"
sizes["5-5-inch-iphone-6"]="1242x2208"
sizes["4-7-inch-iphone-6"]="750x1334"
sizes["4-inch-iphone-6"]="640x1096"
sizes["3-5-inch-iphone-4s"]="640x920"
sizes["12-9-inch-ipad-pro-@3"]="2048x2732"
sizes["12-9-inch-ipad-pro-@2"]="2048x2732"
sizes["11-inch-ipad-pro"]="1668x2388"
sizes["10-5-inch-ipad-pro"]="1668x2224"
sizes["9-7-inch-ipad"]="1536x2008"

for i in "${!sizes[@]}"; do
    if [[ "$i" == *"ipad"* ]]; then
        [ -d "$HERE/ipad" ] || continue
        mkdir -p "$HERE/$i"
        cd "$HERE/ipad"
        for file in *.jpg; do
            [ -e "$file" ] || continue
            convert "$file" -resize "${sizes[$i]}"\! "$HERE/$i/$file"
            echo "scaled $file"
        done
    else
        [ -d "$HERE/iphone" ] || continue
        mkdir -p "$HERE/$i"
        cd "$HERE/iphone"
        for file in *.jpg; do
            [ -e "$file" ] || continue
            convert "$file" -resize "${sizes[$i]}"\! "$HERE/$i/$file"
            echo "scaled $file"
        done
    fi
done
```

To use it, put it in a new directory, and create a `/iphone` and an `/ipad` directory next to it. Put your generic ipad and iphone screenshots in those folders. Run the script, it will generate named folders for all sizes.

```
ios_screenshots/
├── run.sh
├── iphone/
│   ├── screenshot_1.jpg
│   ├── screenshot_2.jpg
│   ├── screenshot_3.jpg
├── ipad/
│   ├── screenshot_1.jpg
│   ├── screenshot_2.jpg
│   ├── screenshot_3.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Run your app on the simulator, and save screen shots.
2. Rename those screen shots to 4.7.1 (iPhone 6), 5.5.1 (iPhone 6 plus) and so on.

Comment: Unity apps don't run very well in the emulator

Answer (score 0):

| Inch | Width*Height | Devices |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3.5 | 640 x 960 | iPhone 3+4 |
| 4 | 640 x 1136 | iPhone 5, iPhone 5S, iPhone 5C |
| 4.7 | 750 x 1334 | iPhone 6, iPhone 6S, iPhone 7, iPhone 8 |
| 5.5 | 1242 x 2208 | iPhone 6 Plus, iPhone 6S Plus, iPhone 7 Plus, iPhone 8 Plus |
| 5.8 | 1125 x 2436 | iPhone X, iPhone XS |
| 6.1 | 828 x 1792 | iPhone XR |
| 6.5 | 1242 x 2688 | iPhone 13 Pro Max, iPhone 12 Pro Max, iPhone 11 Pro Max, iPhone XS Max, iPhone XR |
| 6.7 | 1290 x 2796 | iPhone 14 Pro Max |
| 7.9 | 1536 x 2048 | iPad Mini 2, iPad Mini 3, iPad Mini 4 |
| 9.7 | 1536 x 2048 | iPad 3, iPad 4, iPad Pro, iPad Air, iPad Air 2 |
| 10.5 | 1668 x 2224 | iPad Pro |
| 12.9 | 2048 x 2732 | iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th generation) |
| 1.5 | 272 x 340 | Apple Watch Series 1, Apple Watch Series 2, Apple Watch Series 3 - 38mm |
| 1.57 | 394 x 324 | Apple Watch Series 4 - 40mm |
| 1.65 | 312 x 390 | Apple Watch Series 1, Apple Watch Series 2, Apple Watch Series 3 - 42mm |
| 1.78 | 448 x 368 | Apple Watch Series 4 - 44mm |

Answer (score -2):

You need 6.5 inc(1242 x 2688) - 5.5 inc (1242 x 2208) for iPhone

12.9 inc(2048 x 2732) for iPad

You can get all inc and piksel size
[from the link](https://www.screensizes.app/?source=iphone&type=displays&id=013)

Comment: `My answer different from others` I see the same information in the specifications from Apple in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62241682/2227743

Comment: @EricAya seems like you are right but source is different

Answer (score -4):

These details Gives By Log...

**For iPhone 6 Plus**

```
Screen bounds: {{0, 0}, {414, 736}}, Screen resolution: <UIScreen: 0x7f97fad330b0; bounds = {{0, 0}, {414, 736}}; 
mode = <UIScreenMode: 0x7f97fae1ce00; size = 1242.000000 x 2208.000000>>, scale: 3.000000, nativeScale: 3.000000
```

**For iPhone 6**

```
Screen bounds: {{0, 0}, {375, 667}}, Screen resolution: <UIScreen: 0x7fa01b5182d0; bounds = {{0, 0}, {375, 667}}; 
mode = <UIScreenMode: 0x7fa01b711760; size = 750.000000 x 1334.000000>>, scale: 2.000000, nativeScale: 2.000000
```