# Full resolution screenshots for Iphone 6 and 6+

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm trying to submit a new application to the AppStore but now Apple requires screenshots for iPhone 4.7-Inch and 5.5-Inch. What is the best method to make these screenshot with the full resolution without the device? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 52, accepted):

In Xcode 6 GM run your app with the iPhone 6 or iPhone 6 Plus in the simulator and then hit cmd-s. This will save a screenshot to your computer.

iPhone 6 / iPhone 6 Plus as seen in Xcode 6 GM:

[image: iPhone 6 Plus in Xcode]

How to save a screenshot in the simulator:

[image: Save Screenshot in Simulator]

EDIT:

Make sure Window => Scale is set to 100% in the simulator, else you have the correct device, but end up with the wrong dimensions in the screenshot. – Jos

Comment: Any thoughts about an app that cannot run in the simulator?

Comment: Make sure Window => Scale is set to 100% in the simulator, else you have the correct device, but end up with the wrong dimensions in the screenshot.

Comment: Is there an updated answer for Xcode 12 in 2021?  I can't get a pixel-accurate screenshot in the simulator.

Answer (score 9):

For anybody looking for the resolution of the image to upload (if you want to create some fancy photoshop screenshots), they are:

- iPhone 6: 750 × 1334
- iPhone 6 Plus: 1242 × 2208

[Edit]
Good reference guide here: http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/iphone-6-screens-demystified (talks about resolutions and downsampling of the iPhone 6+).

Comment: Not according to the screenshot I just took from the simulator. This size worked when I uploaded to iTunes Connect. Perhaps Apple is confused in their marketing materials.

Comment: These are the sizes that are used for scaling older Apps on the new phones, so they are correct in this case. The Apple docs are correct because Apps designed for the new iPhones can use all the pixels.

Comment: I'm confused. The screen grabs I just made from my actual iPhone 6 device are 640x1136

Comment: @ChrisPrince maybe too late, but as a reference, I just discovered that when you're using the simulator in scaled window size, the screenshots are not taken at full resolution but scaled too. Just switch to full resolution -unscaled- mode (Cmd+1) and then save the screenshot (Cmd+S). It should be in the correct size now.

Comment: Thanks! @Alejandro Iván

Comment: But I still would like to know why, when I do a screen grab (Home+Power) on my actual iPhone6 device, they come out as 640x1136.

Comment: I just figured this out. In Settings > Display & Brightness, you have to have the setting of Standard. I had my device set to zoomed. With "Zoomed" you get 640x1136 screen grabs. With "Standard", you get 750x1134. Not obvious to me!

Comment: @Chris Prince - thank you!  This was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE 2018**

- Open Debug. Then, unchecked "Optimized Rendering for Window Size"

You'll get full resolution of the image. Hope this will help!

Comment: Thanks, would never have thought of this!

Comment: Hm, I'm not able to capture the correct size from device or simulator. Unchecking suggested option does nothing here..

Answer (score 2):

Download Xcode 6 GM from Apple
      https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/

Answer (score 2):

**For iPhone 6 Plus**

```
Screen bounds: {{0, 0}, {414, 736}}, Screen resolution: <UIScreen: 0x7f97fad330b0; bounds = {{0, 0}, {414, 736}}; 
mode = <UIScreenMode: 0x7f97fae1ce00; size = 1242.000000 x 2208.000000>>, scale: 3.000000, nativeScale: 3.000000

**For iPhone 6**

Screen bounds: {{0, 0}, {375, 667}}, Screen resolution: <UIScreen: 0x7fa01b5182d0; bounds = {{0, 0}, {375, 667}}; 
mode = <UIScreenMode: 0x7fa01b711760; size = 750.000000 x 1334.000000>>, scale: 2.000000, nativeScale: 2.000000
```