# How do I set the iOS Simulator to the iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus screen resolutions?

Tags: ios, iphone, simulator

I don't see the drop downs for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus is Xcode, but I do see the resizable iPhone and iPad settings. Can someone tell me what settings to put in for the iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus to make the simulator simulate the right screen sizes?

Comment: Here your answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25757118/3800154 
downloard new version of xcode

Comment: possible duplicate of [Full resolution screenshots for Iphone 6 and 6+](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25756863/full-resolution-screenshots-for-iphone-6-and-6)

Comment: I didn't specify that I was in the GM in my question, but I was. Turned out to be that I needed to remove the old version of Xcode first before I installed the new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just download xcode 6 gm seed, which was released yesterday.

[image]

Comment: I've already downloaded it. Maybe I'm running the wrong version... will report back.

Comment: Well, I just dragged it over the old one and that apparently didn't work, or maybe I left the simulator open and those files didn't get updated, but a reinstall fixed it. Thanks for the quick answer :)

Answer (score 4):

In nav bar --> Go to Product/Destination/Add Additional simulators - there you'll have dropdown list with all the latest simulators you can install

Hope this helps

[image: Example]

Comment: best and safest