# App store screenshots sizes for all devices

Tags: iphone

I need screenshots size(App store Screenshot) for iphone 6 and iphone 6 plus.I am unable to get the screenshots size from iTunes Connect Guide.Thanks in advance.

Comment: [iPhone 7 answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33173632/3681880) (still the same as iPhone 6)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus screenshots don't accept cropped (without status bar) uploads.

**6.5in (iPhone XS Max):**
1242 x 2688px portrait

**5.8in (iPhone XR):**
828 x 1792px portrait

**5.8in (iPhone X, iPhone XS):**
1125 x 2436px portrait

**5.5in (iPhone 6 Plus, iPhone 6S Plus, iPhone 7 Plus, iPhone 8 Plus):**
1242 × 2208px portrait

**4.7in (iPhone 6, iPhone 6s, iPhone 7, iPhone 8):**
750 × 1334px portrait

**4in (iPhone 5, iPhone 5S, iPhone 5C):**
640 × 1096px portrait (without status bar) minimum
640 × 1136px portrait (full screen) maximum
1136 × 600px landscape (without status bar) minimum
1136 × 640px landscape (full screen) minimum

**3.5in (iPhone 4, iPhone 4S):**
640 × 920px portrait (without status bar) minimum
640 × 960px portrait (full screen) maximum
960 × 600px landscape (without status bar) minimum
960 × 640px landscape (full screen) maximum

Comment: They don't accept cropped uploads, but the docs also explicitly say "Don't include the device status bar in your screenshots." What's up with that?

Comment: @AlexRyan I think that means give the full size screenshot, but remove the status bar text (like the antenna, clock, battery...) so it doesn't interfere with a user's actual status bar.

Comment: Can I add the iPad and iPad Pro sizes?

Answer (score 29):

If you just want a direct representation of your app views:

- run the app in the simulator (for each different device type) and
- press **cmd+s** for each view/screen you want to show in the App Store and it will save a screenshot of the correct dimensions for you to upload directly.

The screenshots are saved to your desktop with a name starting 'iOS Simulator Screen Shot' - this has saved me loads of time in creating the App Store shots!

Comment: This is brilliant! Thanks a lot for sharing this.

Comment: Make sure if you use cmd+s you have window -> scale set to 100%

Comment: Having used this method for some time now, I recently submitted an app update for a live app and it was rejected because I had used simulator screenshots!! Why do Apple insist on making developers' lives difficult?  I had to go through all my screenshots and paste a grey band over the top bar where the simulator was mentioned & re-upload them!

Comment: The question is: how to take screenshot of window content without title and shadow?

Answer (score 2):

The resolutions are:

iPhone 6: 1334 x 750
iPhone 6 Plus: 2208 x 1242

See the following threads:

[Full resolution screenshots for Iphone 6 and 6+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25756863/full-resolution-screenshots-for-iphone-6-and-6)
[iTunes Connect Screenshots Sizes for all iOS (iPhone/iPad/Apple Watch) devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25756589/new-screenshots-size-for-iphone-6-itunesconnect)

Comment: What about status bar?

Comment: The screenshot sizes remain the same, with or without status bar.

Answer (score 0):

The Resolutions are:

iPhone 6: It was used Retina display(2X) and screen size is 4.7inch diagonally.

```
      750x1334px Portrait
      1334x750px Landscape
```

iPhone 6 Plus: It was used Retina display(3X) and screen size is 5.5inch diagonally.

```
      1242 × 2208px Portrait
      2208 x 1242p× Landscape
```

These details Gives By Log...

**For iPhone 6 Plus**

```
Screen bounds: {{0, 0}, {414, 736}}, Screen resolution: <UIScreen: 0x7f97fad330b0; bounds = {{0, 0}, {414, 736}}; 
mode = <UIScreenMode: 0x7f97fae1ce00; size = 1242.000000 x 2208.000000>>, scale: 3.000000, nativeScale: 3.000000
```

**For iPhone 6**

```
Screen bounds: {{0, 0}, {375, 667}}, Screen resolution: <UIScreen: 0x7fa01b5182d0; bounds = {{0, 0}, {375, 667}}; 
mode = <UIScreenMode: 0x7fa01b711760; size = 750.000000 x 1334.000000>>, scale: 2.000000, nativeScale: 2.000000
```

Other details related to Launcher,App icon and Bar Buttons and more....

see this link https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1

Answer (score 0):

## iPhone 6

> If your app indicates that it is optimized for the iPhone 6, 
>   at least one 4.7-inch screenshot is required. Up to four
>   additional screenshots can be uploaded. You can rearrange the 
>   screenshots when you create or edit the iTunes Connect record.
>
> Don't include the device status bar in your screenshots.
>
> Screenshot requirements are:
>
> - 72 dpi, RGB, flattened, no transparency
> - High-quality JPEG or PNG image file format
> - 750 x 1334 pixels for hi-res portrait
> - 1334 x 750 pixels for hi-res landscape
>
> [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html)

---

## iPhone 6 Plus

> If your app indicates that it is optimized for the iPhone 6 Plus, 
>   at least one 5.5-inch screenshot is required. Up to four additional 
>   screenshots can be uploaded. You can rearrange the screenshots when 
>   you create or edit the iTunes Connect record.
>
> Don't include the device status bar in your screenshots.
>
> Screenshot requirements are:
>
> - 72 dpi, RGB, flattened, no transparency
> - High-quality JPEG or PNG image file format
> - 1242 x 2208 pixels for hi-res portrait
> - 2208 x 1242 pixels for hi-res landscape
>
> [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html)

Comment: Where do you indicate whether an app is optimized for iPhone 6/6+? Is it in the info.plist?

Comment: I believe you just set "Latest SDK" and in the plist the minimum deployment target you require.  Same as for past versions..  I'm not certain to tell you the truth though.

Comment: You need to provide a launch image for the iPhone 6/iPhone 6+ screen sizes in order to be considered optimized for those devices. If a launch image is provided, it will use the native display size; if not, it will use the iPhone 5 screen size and scale it up to fill the screen.

Comment: if you set a launch XIB or storyboard file. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html