# iTunes Connect Screenshot for iPhone 6/6Plus without Status Bar?

Tags: ios, iphone, screenshot, app-store-connect

Other posts are talking about iPhone6 and 6 Plus screenshot size for iTunes Connect

**iPhone 6**:

- 750 x 1334 pixels for hi-res portrait
- 1334 x 750 pixels for hi-res landscape

**iPhone 6 Plus**:

- 1242 x 2208 pixels for hi-res portrait
- 2208 x 1242 pixels for hi-res landscape.

However they have to be uploaded without the status bar, so these dimensions do not look correct.

iTunes Connect Developer Guide gives different suggestions for 4S, 5 in case of including or not including the status bar, but not for the iPhone 6 and 6Plus, for which only the full size are provided.

Answer (score 7):

Just ran into the same problem: I removed the status bar on all my screenshots (as I used to do it for the older iPhone models) only to learn that this does not work anymore for iPhone 6.

I looked at the screenshots of Apple's own apps (e. g. Pages). They do leave the status bar in, but it doesn't show a carrier and times is set to 9:41. This can be done by connecting the iPhone to a Mac and using it as camera input through Quicktime on Yosemite (like for app-previews).

Comment: This can also be done using this project on GitHub: [shinydevelopment/SimulatorStatusMagic](https://github.com/shinydevelopment/SimulatorStatusMagic)

Answer (score 3):

Screenshots for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus must be uploaded WITH status bar, e.g.:
[App store screenshots sizes for all devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25783705/app-store-screenshots-size-for-iphone-6-and-iphone-6-plus)

The Apple Dev Guide hasn't been updated for iPhone 6 and 6 Plus, you are right.
Remember the iPhone 6 Plus screenshot dimensions differ slightly from the real resolution. See:
http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/iphone-6-screens-demystified

(downsampling marked red in the webpage, no need to download the guide to see it).

Comment: Tnxs for the answer, however here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html Apple is clearly saying that on iPhone6 and 6Plus: Don't include the device status bar in your screenshots...

Comment: However, that documentation is obsolete. Maybe Apple will change what they are asking for. As you may have noticed, iPhone 6 / 6 Plus are not included in the link you provided.

Comment: Yes it is included. It is a few days it is included and that's why I am asking. If you scroll the pages you can see that since a few days they included the 4.7 and 5.5 inches screens... For those dimension they give only the full size but they are pointing out to remove the status bar...

Comment: You're right. They included the sizes. I was expecting to see the images of the phones, as in older devices, but they aren't there yet. You may look for iPhone 6 screenshots by searching: >>"optimized for iphone 6" site:itunes.apple.com<< the first 5 results I see show either there is status bar or there is a design frame and the status bar inside also. This isn't conclusive, but indicates the Apple documentation is 1. Contradictory and 2. Only screenshots with status bar can be uploaded, without deforming the images.

Comment: If you take a screenshot of your and crop out the status bar, iTunes Connect rejects the image because it's not the expected size. For the 4.7 phone, it wanted exactly 750x1334, which is the size that includes the status bar. Sigh.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding at this point is that you have to photoshop the status bar out.
I looked at Uber's app, and they had the status bar in there, with the time stamp and wifi bar.

So I guess its all round confusion.