# Size of screenshot in iPhone6

Tags: ios, size, screenshot

I took a screenshot of my app on iPhone6. However, the size for this screenshot is 640 * 1136. 
  According to documents for apple, the size for iPhone6 screenshot should be 750 * 1334.
  I just cannot figure out the reason for the wrong screenshot size.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25959766/itunes-connect-screenshot-for-iphone-6-6plus-without-status-bar

Comment: I read that. It's said iPhone6 screenshot should be 750 * 1334. Still do not know why mine is  640 * 1136.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See this link: http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions
You can change display zoom at Settings