# iTunes Connect Screenshots Continue to Fail

Tags: app-store-connect

I'm trying to upload new images to iTunes Connect. However, they continue to fail. I've checked many many times now and no dice. The screenshot sizes match Apple's requirements. Saving it as a .jpg continues to fail. Saving it as a .png with no Alpha continues to fail. Spent most of my work day on here finding other solutions that I've tried and still fails.

Other things I tried was using different browsers, saving the image file as generic as possible (ex. 1.png, and I've tried using screenshots pulled from an actual device as well as the Xcode simulator.

I am trying to do this via a windows machine. Has anybody been able to successfully upload screenshots through iTunes Connect using a Windows machine? At this point that is the only thing I can think of as to why it continues to fail.

Comment: What error message do you see when your screenshots fail?

Comment: try a different browser, Chrome for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Try waiting... in my experience, iTunes connect is not all that reliable, and waiting a day solved the screenshot upload issue for me.

Also, if you have not already, open the screenshots in an image editor, and insure they are exactly the right size... I have found that my screenshots always end up a pixel to skinny for some reason.

Lastly, keep in mind [new rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25783705/app-store-screenshots-size-for-iphone-6-and-iphone-6-plus) for the iPhone 6 and 6 Plus.

Comment: Thanks. Although we've been at it for almost a week now. It could be any moment where Apple approves the new build.