# What's the easiest way to get Screenshot for your app, for App Store submission?

Tags: app-store, appstore-approval

What's the easiest way to get screenshots for app submission to Apple's App Store, and what are the various sizes that need to be included?

Also, is the status bar allowed? I believe I've heard it's not, but a ton of apps including Facebook and Quora include the status bar in their screenshots.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25783705/app-store-screenshots-sizes-for-all-devices might help you

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Let's start off with saying that the status bar is allowed in the screenshots, however not encouraged and in [Apple's Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW2) it says that it shouldn't be included.
As to your second question, there are a few methods. Firstly, you have to have a screenshot for the current major screen sizes: 5.5", 6.5".If you have an iPad version, then 12.9" iPad is also required. How to make good screenshots:

**Method 1:**
Use your own devices. If you in any case have enough devices lying around at home or from friends, you can use them to take screenshots. You can either manually press home and power button at the same time, or my preferred method, connect your device to your computer. In Xcode open device manager by  clicking `CMD + SHIFTt + 2`. Select your device, and in the detailed view you'll see the screenshot button.
[image: Take Screenshot]. This is rather tedious and takes a lot of time.

**EDIT 2020**
As correctly pointed out by The Trav, Launchkit was aqquired by Google, and is now available as open source code. There are alternatives a simple google search will reveal.

**Method 2 - DEPRECATED:**

Use a website to create your screenshots. This is my number one favourite, as it only requires one screenshot and then creates beautiful App Store images. I am in no way affiliated with them.It's a service from Launch Kit called Screenshot builder. You can make beautiful images, as seen in their example below. [Launch Kit Screenshot Builder](https://launchkit.io/screenshots)
[image: Examples]

**Method 3:**

Lastly, you can create them yourself for every device size yourself in Photoshop or any other editing software you have.
For that you need the following specifications:

- 72 dpi, RGB, flattened, no transparency
- High-quality JPEG or PNG image file format

6.5": 1 1284 x 2778 pixels **portrait** || 2778 x 1284 pixels **landscape**

5.5": 1242 x 2208 pixels **portrait** || 2208 x 1242 pixels **landscape**

12.9" iPad: 2048 x 2732 pixels **portrait** || 2732 x 2048 pixels **landscape**

All of the info for the last method can also be found in [Apple's Guidelines.](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devd274dd925)

Comment: looks like launchkit is no longer running screenshot builder as a SaaS.  Though the project is available if you want to run it yourself

Comment: I checked the link to Apple's guide but I don't find it mentioned in any place that status bar was not suggested.

Comment: I'm using this tool https://appscreen.studio/ its free for 3 projects screenshot generations per month

Answer (score 9):

Check out [AppScreens.com](https://appscreens.com)

AppScreens is one of the only systems that can generate all required screenshots from a single responsive template making the process fast and efficient. You design once, and AppScreens automatically sizes the elements and text consistently within each export frame.

It supports the creation of all required Apple App Store (and Google Play Store) at once. As of 2022 these are as follows (in the highest resolution);

- ***6.7” Display*** > `1290 x 2796 pixels`
- ***6.5” Display*** > `1242 x 2688 pixels` || `1284 x 2778 pixels`
- ***6.1” Display*** > `1179 x 2556 pixels`
- ***5.5” Display*** > `1242 x 2208 pixels`
- ***12.9" Display (2nd + 3rd gen)*** > `2048 x 2732 pixels`
- ***Mac*** > `2880 x 1800 pixels`
- ***Apple Watch*** > `396 x 484 pixels`
- ***+10 for Android!***

[image]

AppScreens has now exported over ***2m screenshots***, and is the most fully featured screenshot tool on web. It supports real, clay & coloured devices, automatic font size matching, panoramic backgrounds, 3D devices, templates, landscape projects, etc. It also includes all of the essential design frills such as rich text, 950+ fonts, real-time previews, language localization, highest resolution downloads, and much more. AppScreens is free to use with some limited features, or you can upgrade to use Pro features.

***Note, shameless plug***: I am the developer. We've built this to assist in the creation of these assets for our own apps. We've wasted too much time over the years battling with image editors & other half-baked tools.

Comment: Just tried this, and it's really a great tool. Well done!

Comment: I agree on that, this is the best free tool.

Comment: Not free.  But still cool.

Comment: @AndrewEinhorn Thanks for checking it out! We have both a free plan and paid plan in AppScreens. With the free plan, you can export high-res unwatermarked screenshots, ready for App Store release - totally free. 100s of our users each day opt for this :)

Comment: @Ralpharoo does appscreens have API so that I can use in my CI/CD pipeline?

Answer (score 8):

How about using the Xcode Simulator it self, This would get you the correct resolution with no pain, Just put your app on the desired simulator and save screen by clicking CMD+S will export a screenshot on your desktop with the exact desired resolution.

Here I try it with iPhone 11 Pro Max Simulator (I'm using Xcode 12 on a Big Sur)

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do you know all the resolutions for each device that the app store is asking for?

Comment: https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devd274dd925

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is to use a tool like Screenshop - Screenshot Creator. Its a tool for macOS, which helps to create nice screenshots for the App Store very easily. 
Predefined screenshot sizes can be chosen for iPhone, iPad, Mac in portrait or landscape mode. Its also useful for Android screenshots or web presentations.
There is also a free test Version available.

I've created very nice screenshots within minutes with the tool, after spending hours and getting frustrated by using image editors before.

Here is the website for the tool: http://screenshop.zidarts.com
Which includes a demo video.
And here is the direct link to the demo video on youtube: https://youtu.be/yjiGRqTBA_4

Answer (score 4):

## Try https://previewed.app/

You can create beautiful screenshots, with AppStore approved dimensions in a few clicks.

In the end you end up with something like:

[image]

#### Update 2022:

Recently saw ads and tried using [Screenshots Pro](https://screenshots.pro)

Reasons to switch:

- Free
- Localization
- Auto export to multiple devices (iPhone 4", 5.5" and 6.5" devices for example, same for iPad)
- API access (Haven't tested, but you can integrate something like [Fast Lane](https://fastlane.tools/) to create screenshots and then use them in Screenshots Pro for post-processing)

Answer (score 3):

Updated 2020.

For iPhone, screenshots for 6.5-inch iPhone Xs Max and 5.5-inch devices (iPhone 6s Plus, iPhone 7 Plus, iPhone 8 Plus) are required. These screenshots will scale down for smaller device sizes.

For iPad, screenshots for 12.9-inch iPad Pro (2nd generation) and 12.9-inch iPad Pro (3rd generation) are required. These screenshots will scale down for smaller device sizes.

[Apple link](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devd1093d90d).

Answer (score 1):

Recently things have changed. Now you only need two sets of screenshots : 5.5" and 12.9 " screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way to create screenshots for free: https://screenshots.us/

Answer (score 0):

I use the [InstaMocks](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.instamocks&hl=en_US) app. It's free and has a ton of built in Android and iOS devices. I've been using it for app store images and to promote my app, [FitJo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mullr.flutterliftkit), on Instagram and it's saved me a ton of time.

It also has material colors built, a color picker, and the option to add images as the background.