# What screenshots to submit in App Store Connect, for new Xamarin iOS app

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I'm confused re what screenshots to submit in App Store Connect, for new Xamarin iOS app. The app is designed to run on iPad, and was designed using the Xamarin iOS Storyboard tool using constraints to create 2 basic layouts: "iPad Pro 12.9 inch" and "iPad Pro 9.7 inch".

In App Store Connect, under Prepare for Submission, if you click "Show all sizes in Media Manager", under "iPad Pro 12.9-inch display" there's a subsection for "9.7 inch display" and is says for that size, use "iPad Pro 12.9-inch display".

And under "iOS Screenshot Properties", under 9.7-inch iPad, for "Screenshot source" it says "Default is scaled 12.9-inch iPad pro".

But my 12.9-inch and 9.7-inch layouts, as designed in Storyboard, are different -- can't just scale to 12.9-inch to 9.7-inch.

So am confused as to what to submit. Any help appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31305907/whats-the-easiest-way-to-get-screenshot-for-your-app-for-app-store-submission

Answer (score 2):

The only required screenshots for an iPad app are the iPad Pro 12.9-inch (2. Generation), which his 2048 x 2732px or 2732 x 2048px. If you don't upload any other screenshots, those will get displayed for all other devices.

If you want (!) to display different screenshots, you can upload extra ones for all other iPad screen sizes. I put together a "shorter" overview here: https://docs.appmanager.io/docs/screenshot-sizes

Even if your interface on the 9.7-inch iPad is different, this is purely optional. The easiest way to take screenshots on devices you don't own is via Xcode/Simulator.