# I'm confused on all the screenshots required for App Store submission, and how to get them

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

[This stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25783705/app-store-screenshots-sizes-for-all-devices) has the sizes, as does the [iTunes Connect App Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW1).

However, I don't quite understand the sizes required.

My app will be for 4S, 5, 6, 6+. It also will technically run on the iPad.

I would like to take full advantage of what the App Store allows, and submit 5 screenshots.

Am I correct in that the only thing REQUIRED, is the 3.5 and 4 inch retina screenshots? What about with or without the status bar? It sounds like that decision is up to me, correct?

It mentions if my app is 'optimized for iPhone 6 or 6+'. What is this? I would probably say my app is optimized for iPhone 6. Should I mark this or leave it open?

I would like to submit 5 different screenshots (portrait only). I would also like to include the status bar. So it sounds like I need to submit 5 for 3.5" retina display (640x960), 5 for 4" retina display (640x1136), 5 4.7" retina display (750x1334), and 5 for 5.5" retina display (1242x2208). None for iPad, since my app is iPhone only. Is this all correct?

Are screenshots taken via the iOS Simulator acceptable for submission? Is there a way to standardize all the Battery Powers and Times to be the same, since it will likely take 10 minutes to take these 20 screenshots?

Comment: Its very simple, Select your simulator window, Go to File=>Save Screen shot. If you want to add iphone5s screen shot than run your app in IPhone5 simulator and take screen shot.

Comment: I'm having this same problem.  Hardware and simulator screenshots are all being kicked back as being the wrong size, despite matching the listed requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Yoy can take screenshots from simulator with it status bar. It will be approved for appstore. But better way its make screenshots in image editor( like ps,skatch and other).
u must make at least 3 screenshots for everyone screen(4,5,6,6+).

Comment: Does not work.  Simulator screenshots are kicked back with "The dimensions of one or more of your screenshots are wrong."