# what are iphone 4.7in and 5.5in screen shot dimensions?

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store-connect

iTunes Connect asks me for screen shots before publishing my app for distribution in the app store. I know that the screen shot dimension for iPhone 4 in is 640x1136, but what are the screen shot dimension for the newer iPhone 4.7 in and 5.5 in?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

### Updated for the new iPhones 11, 11 Pro, 11 Pro Max, X, X, X Max and X.

Size for **iPhone 11 Pro Max** with **@3x** scaling, coordinate space: **414 x 896** points and **1242 x 2688** pixels, 458 ppi, device physical size is 3.06 x 6.22 in or 77.8 x 158.0 mm. 6.5" Super Retina XDR display.

Size for **iPhone 11 Pro** with **@3x** scaling, coordinate space: **375 x 812** points and **1125 x 2436** pixels, 458 ppi, device physical size is 2.81 x 5.67 in or 71.4 x 144.0 mm. 5.8" Super Retina XDR display.

Size for **iPhone 11** with **@2x** scaling, coordinate space: **414 x 896** points and **828 x 1792** pixels, 326 ppi, device physical size is 2.98 x 5.94 in or 75.7 x 150.9 mm. 6.1" Liquid Retina HD display.

Size for **iPhone X Max** with **@3x** scaling (Apple name: **Super Retina HD 6.5 display"**), coordinate space: **414 x 896** points and **1242 x 2688** pixels, 458 ppi, device physical size is 3.05 x 6.20 in or 77.4 x 157.5 mm.

```
let screen = UIScreen.main
print("Screen bounds: \(screen.bounds), Screen resolution: \(screen.nativeBounds), scale: \(screen.scale)")
//iPhone X Max Screen bounds: (0.0, 0.0, 414.0, 896.0), Screen resolution: (0.0, 0.0, 1242.0, 2688.0), scale: 3.0
```

Size for **iPhone X** with **@2x** scaling (Apple name: **Super Retina HD 6.1" display**), coordinate space: **414 x 896** points and **828 x 1792** pixels, 326 ppi, device physical size is 2.98 x 5.94 in or 75.7 x 150.9 mm.

```
let screen = UIScreen.main
print("Screen bounds: \(screen.bounds), Screen resolution: \(screen.nativeBounds), scale: \(screen.scale)")
//iPhone X Screen bounds: (0.0, 0.0, 414.0, 896.0), Screen resolution: (0.0, 0.0, 828.0, 1792.0), scale: 2.0
```

Size for **iPhone X** and **iPhone X** with **@3x** scaling (Apple name: **Super Retina HD 5.8" display**), coordinate space: **375 x 812** points and **1125 x 2436** pixels, 458 ppi, device physical size is 2.79 x 5.65 in or 70.9 x 143.6 mm.

```
let screen = UIScreen.main
print("Screen bounds: \(screen.bounds), Screen resolution: \(screen.nativeBounds), scale: \(screen.scale)")
//iPhone X and X Screen bounds: (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 812.0), Screen resolution: (0.0, 0.0, 1125.0, 2436.0), scale: 3.0
```

Size for **iPhone 8 Plus** (6, 6s, 7 and 8 Plus) with @3x scaling (Apple name: **Retina HD 5.5**), Coordinate space: **414 x 736** points and **1242 x 2208** pixels, 401 ppi, screen physical size is 2.7 x 4.8 in or **68 x 122 mm**.

Size for **iPhone 8** (6, 6s and iPhone 7) with @2x scaling (Apple name: **Retina HD 4.7**), Coordinate space: **375 x 667** points and **750 x 1334** pixels, 326 ppi, screen physical size is 2.3 x 4.1 in or **58 x 104 mm**.

And **iPhone 5** for comparison is 640 x 1136, **iPhone 4** 640 x 960.

**Note:** To build Apps that utilize the full screen size of the new phones add LaunchImages in the sizes: **1242 x 2208**, **2208 x 1242** and **750 x 1334**. The size in simulator will be different before these LaunchImages are added, because older Apps are scaled.

[image: Comparing iPhone 6 and 6 Plus]

Comment: I think `Retina HD 4.7` is misleading. By `Retina HD`, we usually think of `@3x`

Comment: @onmyway133 I agree with you. Apple is also using Retina 5K display for the new iMacs, instead of just 5K. This is marketing as Apple started the "Retina" trend with iPhone 4. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retina_Display

Comment: Does anyone know about the size of iPhone 7?

Comment: @AnuragSharma The iPhone 7 sizes are the same as iPhone 6 and 6 Plus

Comment: @HannesSverrisson Thank you , I was a bit confused but now it's clear

Answer (score 10):

You may find this info useful too, taken from Andy Orsow's article (thank you buddy!) [What are the iOS screen sizes?](https://support.invisionapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/203009779-What-are-the-iOS-screen-sizes-):

---

The sizes below include the iOS status bar area, so be sure to leave room for that in your designs. See the bottom of this article for status bar information.

Remember, mobile projects can scroll, so the screen heights listed below are simply minimum heights for your designs.

### Phones

**iPhone 6 Plus**
Portrait: 1242 x 2208 (`Launch Image:` iPhone Portrait iOS8 – Retina HD 5.5)
Landscape: 2208 x 1242 (Phone Landscape iOS8 – Retina HD 5.5)

**iPhone 6**
Portrait: 750 x 1334 (iPhone Portrait iOS8 – Retina HD 4.7)
Landscape: 1334 x 750

**iPhone 5, 5S, 5C**
Portrait: 640 x 1136 ("iPhone Portrait iOS5,6 – Retina 4" and "iPhone Portrait iOS7,8 – Retina 4")
Landscape: 1136 x 640

**iPhone 4, 4S**
Portrait: 640 x 960 (iPhone Portrait iOS5,6 – 2x and iPhone Portrait iOS7,8 – 2x) 
Landscape: 960 x 640

**iPhone 1, 2, and 3**
Portrait: 320 x 480 (iPhone Portrait iOS5,6 – 1x)
Landscape: not supported

### Tablets

**iPad Air / Retina iPad**
Portrait: 1536 x 2048 (iPad Portrait iOS 7-9 - 2x)
Landscape: 2048 x 1536 (iPad Landscape iOS 7-9 - 2x)

**iPad Mini**
Portrait: 1536 x 2048 (iPad Portrait iOS 7-9 - 2x)
Landscape: 2048 x 1536 (iPad Landscape iOS 7-9 - 2x)

**iPad - Non Retina**
Portrait: 768 x 1024 (iPad Portrait iOS 7-9 - 1x)  iOS 5,6?
Landscape: 1024 x 768 (iPad Landscape iOS 7-9 - 1x) iOS 5,6?

### Wearables

**Apple Watch**
42mm: 312x390px
38mm: 272x340px

### Status Bar Info

InVision will overlay a status bar on your designs for you, so including it in your design is up to you. However, you’ll want to make sure you account for the status bar at the top of your screen.

**At the top of your design, leave room for:**

**iPhone 6 Plus:** 60px height

**iPhone 4–6:** 40px height

**iPhone - Non retina:** 20px height

**Retina iPads:** 40px height

**Non-retina iPads:** 20px height

If you don't want to include the status bar in your designs, check the box for “My design starts below the status bar” in your project options.

---

**EDITED:** I had to add Launch Images to my app, and I was not able to find info how simulators correspond to Apple's image names in Launch Images assets. I found such info at http://www.ios-developer.net/iphone-ipad-programmer/icons_and_graphics/default-image and added here.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a comment to Mixaz's answer but I don't have the rep for that yet. Interestingly enough, from [Full resolution screenshots for Iphone 6 and 6+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25756863/full-resolution-screenshots-for-iphone-6-and-6)

> I just figured this out. In Settings > Display & Brightness, you have to have the setting of Standard. I had my device set to zoomed. With "Zoomed" you get 640x1136 screen grabs. With "Standard", you get 750x1334. Not obvious to me! – Chris Prince Nov 18 '15 at 5:03