# New iTunes Connect Screenshot Process - Issue Uploading Primary Device Screenshots

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Just wondering if anyone else is having this issue. I'm unable to drag and drop screenshots (which as 100% the right size) into the new iTunes Connect media uploaded - whether it's on the main app page or in the Media Manager.

> It just says that it's already using the 5.5-inch shots (of which there are none) and won't give me the ability to upload.

Interestingly, if I uncheck one of the smaller sizes I can drag screenshots to those just fine.

Screenshot of the issue:-

[image]
[image: Trying to submit it asks for screenshots]

Comment: which error you have get?

Comment: When trying to drag it in nothing - because it isn't actually a drag/drop field (although I think it should be). When I try to submit though, the field turns red and asks for screenshots. Added a second screenshot to illustrate this.

Comment: use this link to set the size of you screen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25756589/itunes-connect-screenshots-sizes-for-all-ios-iphone-ipad-apple-watch-devices

Comment: give the size of image in pixel

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the issue - it's 100% not the size of the screenshot. Normally if you upload the wrong size it will tell you right away. It's Apple's website which, to me, look broken in that it is saying my 5.5 inch screenshots will use 5.5 inch screenshots which do not exist - and it wont let me upload anything.

Comment: @DeanSherwin kindly check it : http://stackoverflow.com/a/38950987/1308632

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I update the version of my App, also encountered the same situation. After trying various methods, the solution is found.

1. upload a screenshot of the non-primary language,
   [image]
2. change the primary language,
   [image]
3. modify the non-primary language screenshot,
4. change back the primary language.

Yeah Succeed!!!

Comment: This is the correct answer. Worked for me. Thanks you! :)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug in iTunes Connect that causes the 5.5 inch iPhone (and 12.9 inch iPad) screenshot upload to act identically to the smaller sizes in that it's disabled unless you choose to use a separate screenshot for that size. Except that the checkbox that allows you to do that is hidden in the largest device size in the group (iPhone/iPad). The bug seems to affect some combinations of localizations.

Right now you can play around with the languages as suggested in Bo Lin's answer, [file a bug report to Apple](https://bugreport.apple.com), try to enable the screenshot upload if you're skilled at Angular.js (and I'm not sure if it's actually even possible), or just wait.

Answer (score 0):

You only have to upload 5.5 screen sizes and 12.9 sizes screen shots

```
(Portrait)

5.5 screenshot size : 1242 × 2208

12.9 screenshot size : 2048 × 2732
```