# There are one or more errors on the page

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

Getting "There are one or more errors on the page" but unable to find the exact error.

Here is screenshot

[image]

**Edit 1**

I am trying to upload iPad screenshot with dimension 1536 x 2048 pixels for hi-res portrait (full screen) maximum with Locked but I am getting strange error, given below

[image]

Note: I have tried uploading image from both chrome and safari but getting same error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to submit iOS app for review - "There are one or more errors on the page."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28489438/unable-to-submit-ios-app-for-review-there-are-one-or-more-errors-on-the-page)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting this error because ITC has recently changed rules for uploading Screenshots.

Here are few things you should keep in mind :

**iPhone:**

- For iPhone you must upload 1 set of screen shots for 5.5 inch device (1242x2208 size)
- Kindly take a note that 1 set means you can upload 5 screenshots
- You can upload screenshots of other devices from media manager. But only if your application have localization feature & you need to show other language screenshots

**iPad:**

- For iPad you must have to upload 5 screenshots of 12.9 inch iPad device. (2732x2048)
- You can upload screenshots of other devices from media manager. But only if your application have localization feature & you need to show other language screenshots

Now in your case i can see you are trying to upload iPad retina screenshots but its giving you error message.

**Simply follow this things:**

- Ask designer to create one splash screen for 2732x2048 size & upload it. As because we can add minimum 1 screen shot so you will be submit the application by 1 screenshot only.
- If you have added other device screenshots from media manager than make sure you have localization feature & in that case you have to select other language. Other wise remove that screenshots.

**Important Note:**

- I already tried the same solution & got approval for my app. So its a tried & tested solution & its not on basis of assumptions.

Hope it will help to everyone.

Comment: Thanks a bundle. Uploaded one screenshot of 12.9 inch iPad device. (2732x2048) solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

This error maybe thrown if you **didn't delete** the screenshots of the small screens before checking the boxes `Use 5.5-Inch Display` and `Use 12.9-Inch Display` in **Media Manager**

If so ..

- **Uncheck** all the boxes in the Media Manager
- Click save
- **Delete** all the screenshots of the small screens
- Click save
- **Check** all the boxes
- Click save and then submit the update

Hope this will be helpful ..

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the simplified screenshots where you are ONLY providing the 5.5-inch or 12.9-inch display screenshots, then make sure you go into the Media Manager and have the check enabled for "Use 5.5-Inch Display" or "use 12.9-Inch Display" for your screenshots.

iTunes Connect will not know use the 5.5-Inch screenshots by default for the other screen sizes, so you need to let it know to use them.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same error and fixed it by changing the category of my App in App Info from "Magazines and Newspapers" to Business... I have no idea why.

Comment: Same happened with me as well.I think this is a bug with ItunesConnect