# iTunesConnect app upload iOS Screenshot Properties

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I'm uploading iphone app to app store which supports iOS 9 and above.

Do I need to upload screenshots for all the supported device or iPhone 6 plus(750 x 1334) is fine?

Comment: Have a look at this https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=08082016a and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25756589/itunes-connect-screenshots-sizes-for-all-ios-iphone-ipad-apple-watch-devices, try using media manager.

Answer (score 2):

Do I need to upload screenshots for all the supported device or iPhone 6 plus(750 x 1334) is fine?

**It's fine just upload iPhone 6 Plus images and App Store will take care of rest.**

For App Previews please follow the Apple Guidelines [here](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-previews/).

**iPhone 5, iPhone 5c, iPhone 5s, and iPhone SE**

1920 x 1080 or 1136 x 640 (Landscape)

1080 x 1920 or 640 x 1136 (Portrait)

**iPhone 6, iPhone 6s, and iPhone 7**

1334 x 750 (Landscape)

750 x 1334 (Portrait)

**iPhone 6 Plus, iPhone 6s Plus, and iPhone 7 Plus**

1920 x 1080 (Landscape)

1080 x 1920 (Portrait)

Comment: How about preview video size and resolution and max duration?

Comment: @MasterStroke Updated Answer

Answer (score 1):

For App Store you need only 6Plus (Retina HD 5.5) screen shot

iphone 6plus -- 1242 * 2208 pixels

For ipad You need

iPad 12.9 inch --  2048 × 2732 pixels

Answer (score -1):

It is okay to submit the screenshots for a particular device. Apple will use it across device sizes.[See this](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=08082016a)

Comment: Yes. Since 750 * 1334 is the size of 6S devices, It is perfectly ok.

Comment: No, you can only reuse screenshots for devices that have smaller resolutions than the original. So if you submit a 4.7" screenshot in 750x1334 you can use that for 4" and 3.5" as well, but not for the larger 5.5"