# iTunes connect - You must upload a valid screenshot

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

While trying to add Review Information for my In-App-Product I upload a screenshot (successfully) that is 1280x800, no alpha.

I then go to click "save", and it gives me an error message such as:

- > You must upload a valid screenshot
- > Your Screenshot must be a valid size. Learn more

No further information is given. As far as I can tell my screenshot is valid.

I've tried both Firefox and Safari.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Upload screenshots of 1242×2208 resolution (iPhone 6 Plus).

> If your app is the same across device sizes and localizations, you can
>   use the highest resolution screenshot for each device type; this set
>   will scale appropriately for other device sizes when viewed on the App
>   Store in each localization available in iTunes Connect. For example,
>   if your app supports only the iPhone, you can provide 5.5-inch display
>   screenshots and you do not need separate screenshots for the 4.7-inch,
>   4.0-inch and 3.5-inch displays.

See **Screenshot Properties** section [here for details](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/Properties.html)

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me (iPhone 6 Plus, iOS 12.2, Simulator).
A screenshot using iPhone 11 iOS 13.4 in the Simulator didn't work, for whatever reason.

Answer (score 11):

I would like to add to the accepted answer because regurgitating the documentation does little to resolve actual problems.

After taking a screen shot of the app on my device for in app purchase review and it still didn't work, I did some investigating.

After you attempt to upload a screen shot and see the error to upload a valid size, you can open the browser inspector to see the error details. The image MUST be one of these dimensions: 
[accepted resolutions found in console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KgKJ.png)

Something else I didn't realize is when taking screen shots with command-shift-4 on macbooks, when you hold it down for the drag you can see the actual dimensions of the screen shot you are taking, but for some reason it saves it as DOUBLE the size. I ended up taking a screen shot where the cross hairs of the screen shot say 320 x 480 resulting in a saved png of 640x960. It has to be one of the pre set sizes in order for image upload to accept it.

After banging my head on a wall for a couple hours I figured this out, so I hope this helps others .

Comment: I think the double size would happen on a Retina display. Another option in that case is to capture the size you want, then open the image in Preview and resize to 50%.

Comment: `960`x`640` works perfectly, but `1024`x`1024` does not, regarding the list on the screenshot!

Answer (score 4):

Screen shots of the simulator taken via `Command + Shift + 4` or screenshots taken using a real device (even latest iPhone 11) are **not accepted** by App Store Connect.

Instead, use your Simulator in the latest & biggest device mode (currently iPhone 11 Pro Max) and use simulator's menu:

> File > New Screen shot

Or just press `Command + S`.

It saves the screen shot file to the desktop. It will be accepted by App Store Connect.

PS: Just for the sake of more info, this question is related to this one: [iTunes Connect Screenshots Sizes for all iOS (iPhone/iPad/Apple Watch) devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25756589/itunes-connect-screenshots-sizes-for-all-ios-iphone-ipad-apple-watch-devices)

Comment: Perfect for setting a quick purchase up for testing, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

screenshot of the in-app purchase as it appears on the device. This screenshot is used for Apple’s review only and is not displayed on the App Store.

Screenshots requirements are outlined below:

iOS requires at least 640 x 920 pixels.
tvOS requires 1920 x1080 pixels.
macOS requires 1280 x 800 pixels.
After you upload an app review image, you can replace it, but you can’t remove it. You can’t update the screenshot while you in-app purchase is in review.

Answer (score 2):

You are uploading screenshot of wrong size. It must be of at least `640 x 960` or any other size that inherits the iPhone screen size in `2x` or `3x` dimension.

It better you upload screenshot of your iPhone.

[Apple Doc Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW2)

Comment: dont own an iphone, only simulator

Comment: You can take a bigger screenshot from Simulator. Do this, make iPhone Simulator bigger by pressing "CMD key + 1" and then take screenshot using "CMD Key + s"

Answer (score 1):

Run this app into iPhone 8 simulator.
Then take a screenshot using the simulator.
This is how my screenshott upload worked.